# make shared_ptr not use delete

Tags: c++, boost

in my code i would like boost::shared_ptr not to call delete but call ptr->deleteMe() instead.

Also i have a few C styled functions that return a ptr. Can i make it call lib_freeXYZ(ptr); instead of trying to delete?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Or how about using the stl to provide the wrapper functor - Doug T. description but without the custom caller.

```
boost::shared_ptr<T> ptr( new T, std::mem_fun_ref(&T::deleteMe) );
boost::shared_ptr<S> ptr( new S, std::ptr_fun(lib_freeXYZ) );
```

Comment: I actually prefer this, more elegant.

Comment: I needed some clarifications so I added another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962978/boost-smart-pointer-with-custom-deleter. Thanks!

Answer (score 37):

You can give the shared_ptr template a custom deleter function which has the signature

```
  void Deleter( T* ptr);
```

for a boost::shared_ptr

So for Deleter you would do

```
  boost::shared_ptr<T> ptrToT( new T, Deleter );
```

then in the body of Deleter:

```
   void Deleter( T* ptr);
   {
        ptr->deleteMe();
        // And make sure YOU ACTUALLY DELETE (or do whatever else you need to
        // do to release the resource)
        delete ptr;
   }
```

For your specific case when you need something simple (like ptr->deleteMe) see Greg's solution, its very nice.

Comment: i had a similar case where i had to prevent shared_ptr to call delete - it was because the object was allocated statically. may be interesting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363453/looking-for-a-better-c-class-factory#363543

Comment: It may be necessary to make sure `ptr != 0` before dereferencing it in the deleter.  At least I have found that to be the case using std::tr1::shared_ptr on gcc 4.4.5.

Comment: The additional call to `delete ptr` is a bit confusing here -- it's like you want to delete the object twice (first with `ptr->deleteMe()`).  I think normally you would use a deleter because you want to do something _instead of_ `delete ptr`, not _in addition to_.

Comment: You have an extra semicolon in the "body of Deleter" section of code. (`void Deleter( T* ptr);` <-- here )

Answer (score 10):

*Doug T.* answered your question nicely. I'll tell you about intrusive_ptr. Maybe you can use it in your project too.

If you have some C library that has already reference counting, but you have to manually call those functions, you can use `boost::intrusive_ptr` too, and provide proper definitions for its add_ref and release functions. intrusive_ptr will find and call them. They are responsible to increment the reference count and decrement it, freeing the resource when necassary:

```
void intrusive_ptr_add_ref(foo *f) {
    lib_add_ref(f);
}

void intrusive_ptr_release(foo *f) {
    if(lib_dec_ref(f) == 0) 
        lib_free(f);
}
```

Then you can just create objects from raw pointers of type `foo*`. [intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) will call your functions when its copied/destructed:

```
intrusive_ptr<foo> f(lib_alloc());

// can wrap raw pointers too, which already may be referenced somewhere else
foo *p = get_foo_from_somewhere();
function_taking_intrusive_ptr(p);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the C-style data, do as @Doug. T suggested.

For your class, why not do cleanup in a destructor?  Even if this is including deleteMe() in the destructor.

Comment: Perhaps there are some boundary issues? calling delete in a different module could be bad, especially if it is using a different crt instance.

Comment: Indeed.  In that case, an overloaded delete operator?

Comment: Kris - why is Doug answer preferred over Greg answer? Personally, I like the syntax in Greg's answer (especially because I'm dealing with a C library that has a free function for the pointer it returns). But I have no idea about the technical merits or differences.

Comment: @noloader -- I would prefer Greg's. This one was posted before he created the answer though...