# Using mem_fun_ref with boost::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, directx, shared-ptr

Following the advice of [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441306/make-shared-ptr-not-use-delete), I'm trying to get shared_ptr to call [IUnknown::Release()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910902.aspx) instead of delete:

```
IDirectDrawSurface* dds;
... //Allocate dds
return shared_ptr<IDirectDrawSurface>(dds, mem_fun_ref(&IUnknown::Release));
```

> error C2784: 'std::const_mem_fun1_ref_t<_Result,_Ty,_Arg> std::mem_fun_ref(_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(_Arg) const)' : could not deduce template argument for '_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(_Arg) const' from 'ULONG (__cdecl IUnknown::* )(void)'
>
> error C2784: 'std::const_mem_fun_ref_t<_Result,_Ty> std::mem_fun_ref(_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(void) const)' : could not deduce template argument for '_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(void) const' from 'ULONG (__cdecl IUnknown::* )(void)'
>
> error C2784: 'std::mem_fun1_ref_t<_Result,_Ty,_Arg> std::mem_fun_ref(_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(_Arg))' : could not deduce template argument for '_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(_Arg)' from 'ULONG (__cdecl IUnknown::* )(void)'
>
> error C2784: 'std::mem_fun_ref_t<_Result,_Ty> std::mem_fun_ref(_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(void))' : could not deduce template argument for '_Result (__thiscall _Ty::* )(void)' from 'ULONG (__cdecl IUnknown::* )(void)'
>
> error C2661: 'boost::shared_ptr::shared_ptr' : no overloaded function takes 2 arguments

I have no idea what to make of this.  My limited template/functor knowledge led me to try

```
typedef ULONG (IUnknown::*releaseSignature)(void);
shared_ptr<IDirectDrawSurface>(dds, mem_fun_ref(static_cast<releaseSignature>(&IUnknown::Release)));
```

But to no avail.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't the calling convention specifier a problem? Would this be OK?

```
void iUnk_delete(IUnknown* u) {
  u->Release();
}


return shared_ptr<IDirectDrawSurface>(dds, iUnk_delete);
```

Comment: Er, wow, that works.  Thanks!  Do you know why the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441306/make-shared-ptr-not-use-delete) uses `ptr_fun` at all?

Answer (score 6):

`std::mem_fun_ref` doesn't support `stdcall` calling conversion as well as `std::mem_fun` which you could use for pointers.

You could use `boost::mem_fn` instead. You [should define](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/bind/mem_fn.html#Q3) `BOOST_MEM_FN_ENABLE_STDCALL` to work with COM methods.

```
shared_ptr<IDirectDrawSurface>( dds, boost::mem_fn(&IUnknown::Release) );
```

And since your object has the internal reference count you could consider using [`boost::intrusive_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) instead.

Answer (score 3):

I know this maynot be what youa re after but just include ATLBase.h and then use the CComPtr template.

You then just use

```
 CComPtr< IDirect3DSurface9 > surf;
 pDevice->GetBackBuffer( 0, 0, D3DBACKBUFFER_TYPE_MONO, &surf );
```

You can then copy it to another CComPtr and it handles all the AddRefs and Releases for you.  Very useful template class.