# Custom (pool) allocator with boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, allocator

I want objects managed by a shared_ptr to be allocated from a pool, say Boost's Pool interface, how can this be achieved?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's the code to do what you want (probably won't compile as I don't have boost on hand and I'm writing it from memory):

```
class YourClass; // your data type, defined somewhere else

boost::object_pool<YourClass> allocator;

void destroy(YourClass* pointer)
{
    allocator.destroy(pointer);
}

boost::shared_ptr<YourClass> create()
{
    // usage of object_pool<??>::construct requires that you have a 
    // YourClass::YourClass(void) defined. If you need to pass arguments
    // to the new instance, you need to do that separately.
    // 
    // for example using a YourClass::Initialize(your,parameters,here) method
    // before returning from this function
    return boost::shared_ptr<YourClass>( allocator.construct(), &destroy );
}

// usage:
boost::shared_ptr<YourClass>  newObject = create();
```

I implemented this twice, in two different projects. In both, the create and destroy functions were synchronized (you can add a `boost::mutex` lock around the use of allocator) and they were members of a factory class (and the `destroy`'s signature was modified to `void (YourClass*)` through the usage of `boost::bind`).

You can also avoid writing two extra functions (the `destroy` and `create`) by binding `object_pool<YourClass>::destroy` dirrectly in the boost::shared_ptr constructor.

I'm too lazy to write all that now :).

**Edit** (moved my answer comment in here for the code formatting):

To bind the destroy function:

```
class ClassFactory
{
    boost::object_pool<YourClass> allocator;
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<YourClass> create()
    {
        return boost::shared_ptr<YourClass>(
            allocator.construct(),
            boost::bind(&ClassFactory::destroy, this, _1) );
    }

    void destroy(YourClass* pointer)
    {
        allocator.destroy(pointer);
    }
};
```

`ClassFactory` should have a longer lifetime than the `shared_ptr` (if the `ClassFactory` instance is deleted, the this pointer passed to the `shared_ptr` instance will be invalid - and crash your app when the `shared_ptr` deletes the `YourClass` instance).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. I would be interested in seeing how it is done using a factory class, I am having issues in binding the destroy function.

Comment: Do you know whether there is a technical reason for `construct` not taking any arguments?

Comment: I recently did something very similar with a templated pool class and wrote about it here: https://www.burgundywall.com/post/shared_pool

Answer (score 4):

Evident solution:

Create your own `make_shared` function and enforce the use of this method to created `shared_ptr`. Those who derive from The Rule shall be punished.

Note:

There seems to be a confusion with the role of the `shared_ptr`. Its role is to manage memory than YOU have allocated, however to do so it requires some allocation of its own (counter and deleter), thus you may pass it an allocator for those.

Comment: Couldn't you use `boost::allocate_shared` with `boost::pool_alloc`?

Answer (score 1):

These are almost orthogonal concerns. `shared_ptr` plays no part in *allocation* of objects.

Where it *is* concerned is in the *deletion* of memory no longer referenced. If you have allocated from anything other than the default heap you'll need to [provide a custom deleter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441306/make-shared-ptr-not-use-delete)

Comment: As I understand it, shared_ptr can be defined to take a custom allocator:

`template<class Y, class D, class A> shared_ptr(Y * p, D d, A a);`

The question is, what goes for D if I were to use Boost's pool_alloc

Comment: The allocator is for the counter object