# Auto pointer and allocator

Tags: c++

Instead of using try/catch blocks everytime I need to construct any objects after allocating a block of memory for them with an allocator I use internally in my container, I would like to use a class derived from std::auto_ptr (I have no c++11 here) with an overridden destructor, so that it could deallocate the pointed memory and release the pointer afterwards. Are there any disadvantages in doing this?

Comment: Even though you have no C++11, you probably have `shared_ptr` and `unique_ptr` nonetheless (it's C++03 actually). If you don't, you still can use the implementation in boost.

Comment: @PawelZubrycki the allocator I use is a template parameter, which defaults to the classic std::allocator<T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind using `boost` and `boost::shared_ptr<>`, you can provide a custom `deleter`.  See the top 2 answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/441306/make-shared-ptr-not-use-delete) question.