# C++ templated class implementation of the multiton pattern

Tags: c++, singleton, design-patterns, multiton

I implemented the multiton pattern using a templated class in C++.

```
#ifndef MULTITON_H
#define MULTITON_H

#include <map>

template <typename Key, typename T> class Multiton
{
public:    
    static void destroy()
    {
        for (typename std::map<Key, T*>::iterator it = instances.begin(); it != instances.end(); ++it) {
            delete (*it).second;
        }
    }

    static T& getRef(const Key& key)
    {
        typename std::map<Key, T*>::iterator it = instances.find(key);

        if (it != instances.end()) {
            return *(T*)(it->second);
        }

        T* instance = new T;
        instances[key] = instance;
        return *instance;
    }

    static T* getPtr(const Key& key)
    {
        typename std::map<Key, T*>::iterator it = instances.find(key);

        if (it != instances.end()) {
            return (T*)(it->second);
        }

        T* instance = new T;
        instances[key] = instance;
        return instance;
    }

protected:
    Multiton() {}
    virtual ~Multiton() {}

private:
    Multiton(const Multiton&) {}
    Multiton& operator= (const Multiton&) { return *this; }

    static std::map<Key, T*> instances;
};

template <typename Key, typename T> std::map<Key, T*> Multiton<Key, T>::instances;

#endif
```

Usage:

```
class Foo : public Multiton<std::string, Foo> {};
Foo& foo1 = Foo::getRef("foobar");
Foo* foo2 = Foo::getPtr("foobar");
Foo::destroy();
```

Any suggestions for improvements?

Comment: Interesting. I had no idea there is a "Multiton" pattern when i wrote this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/363453/looking-for-a-better-c-class-factory/363543#363543 . I used this term for a completely different meaning :)

Answer (score 3):

1) Personal preference, but I'd reverse the order of the template parameters and default the Key to std::string (if that's what you'll use most)

```
template <typename Key, typename T> class Multiton { ... }
```

Then you can do this:

```
class Foo : public Multiton<Foo> {};
class Bar : public Multiton<Bar,int> {};
```

Which I think is nicer.

2) Also if you're never passing pointers/references to Multitron (which wouldn't kind of violate the patter) you shouldn't need a virtual destructor in the class.

3) If you used a smarter container for your T*s you could avoid having to call Foo::destroy().
Something like `std::map<Key,boost::shared_ptr<T> >` would destroy all the objects when the static instance was destroyed. (Although if you cared about order of destruction, then you'd need something cleverer - you could adapt somethign from existing singleton solutions such as phoenix singletons etc)

4) You could change your iterators to const_iterators.

5) destroy should probably clear the map to prevent accidental access of invalid memory after calling destroy. Or if you want to protect against this you should throw an exception.

```
Foo* foo2 = Foo::getPtr("foobar");
Foo::destroy();
Foo::getPtr("foobar")->doSomething(); // BANG
```

6) If you're not using polymorphic T then you could use a std::map and your code would look like this...

```
template <typename Key, typename T> class Multiton
{
public:
    //Can probably get rid of this guy as maps destructor will do the right thing 
    static void destroy()
    {
        instances.clear();
    }

    static T& getRef(const Key& key)
    {
        return instances[key];
    }

    static T* getPtr(const Key& key)
    {
        return &instances[key];
    }

protected:
    Multiton() {}
    virtual ~Multiton() {}

private:
    Multiton(const Multiton&) {}
    Multiton& operator= (const Multiton&) { return *this; }

    static std::map<Key, T> instances;
};
```

That's about all I can think of for now.

Comment: About your point 6 - can you elaborate on the exact condition for using this simplified code? Where does the non-polymorphism of T come into play?

Comment: If you put an object of type `D` derived from `T` into the map it gets sliced back to its base class T - similar to what calling `T temp = d` does - and the compiler will probably not even tell you. In fact if T is an abstract class you wont even be able to create the map, so the whole thing wont compile.

Answer (score 2):

One improvement would be to rewrite `getRef` to use `getPtr` (or vice versa, the direction doesn't matter so much as [not repeating yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)):

```
static T& getRef(const Key& key)
{
    return *getPtr(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you did very impressive job.

BTW, may I ask why you casted instance (in c-style) here?

```
return (T*)(it->second);
```

I think It would be cleaner if you just write

```
return it->second;
```

Additionally, as this post is 10-years old,
I versioned-up a little bit in modern c++ way, using smart pointer.
Please take a look!

multiton.h

```
#ifndef MULTITON_H
#define MULTITON_H

#include <map>
#include <string>

template <typename T, typename Key = int> class Multiton {
  public:
    static void DestroyAll();
    static void Destroy(const Key &key);
    static std::shared_ptr<T> GetPtr(const Key &key);
    static T &GetRef(const Key &key) { return *GetPtr(key); }

  protected:
    Multiton();
    ~Multiton();

  private:
    Multiton(const Multiton &) = default;
    Multiton &operator=(const Multiton &) = default;
    static std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<T>> instances_;
};

#endif // MULTITON_H
```

multiton.cpp

```
#include "multiton.h"
template <typename T, typename Key> void Multiton<T, Key>::DestroyAll() {
    for (auto it = instances_.begin(); it != instances_.end(); ++it)
        delete (*it).second;
    instances_.clear();
}

template <typename T, typename Key> void Multiton<T, Key>::Destroy(const Key &key) {
    auto it = instances_.find(key);

    if (it != instances_.end()) {
        delete (*it).second;
        instances_.erase(it);
    }
}

template <typename T, typename Key> std::shared_ptr<T> Multiton<T, Key>::GetPtr(const Key &key) {
    const auto it = instances_.find(key);

    if (it != instances_.end())
        return (it->second);

    std::shared_ptr<T> instance = std::make_shared<T>();
    instances_[key] = instance;
    return instance;
}

template <typename T, typename Key> Multiton<T, Key>::Multiton() {}

template <typename T, typename Key> Multiton<T, Key>::~Multiton() {}

template <typename T, typename Key> std::map<Key, std::shared_ptr<T>> Multiton<T, Key>::instances_;
```