# Race condition on x86

Tags: c++, c, x86, race-condition, memory-barriers

Could someone explain this statement:

```
shared variables
x = 0, y = 0

Core 1       Core 2
x = 1;       y = 1;
r1 = y;      r2 = x;
```

How is it possible to have `r1 == 0` and `r2 == 0` on x86 processors?

Source ["The Language of Concurrency" by Bartosz Milewski](http://www.corensic.com/Community/Resources/TheLanguageOfConcurrencyVideo.aspx).

Comment: https://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/ uses an assembly version of this example with/without `mfence` to demo memory reordering, with explanation of why it's allowed to happen.  In C/C++ it's just plain UB if they're not `atomic`; if they are then reordering can only happen with `memory_order_release` or weaker.

Comment: Unfortunately(?) the [tag:memory-order] tag is a synonym for [tag:memory-barriers], so this question about memory ordering can only be tagged with a tag that would prevent reordering.  (At least for a strong enough memory barrier...)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem can arise due to optimizations involving [reordering of instructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution). In other words, both processors can assign `r1` and `r2` **before** assigning variables `x` and `y`, if they find that this would yield better performance. This can be solved by adding a [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier), which would enforce the ordering constraint.

To quote the [slideshow](https://s3.amazonaws.com/corensic/slides/TheLanguageOfConcurrency.pdf) you mentioned in your post:

> Modern multicores/languages break **sequential consistency**.

Regarding the x86 architecture, the best resource to read is [Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual](http://www.intel.com/Assets/PDF/manual/253668.pdf) (Chapter **8.2 Memory Ordering**). Sections 8.2.1 and 8.2.2 describe the memory-ordering implemented by 
Intel486, Pentium, Intel Core 2 Duo, Intel Atom, Intel Core Duo, Pentium 4, Intel 
Xeon, and P6 family processors: a memory model called **processor ordering**, as opposed to **program ordering** (**strong ordering**) of the older Intel386 architecture (where read and write instructions were always issued in the order they appeared in the instruction stream).

The manual describes many ordering guarantees of the processor ordering memory model (such as *Loads are not reordered with other loads*, *Stores are not reordered with other stores*, *Stores are not reordered with older loads* etc.), but it also describes the allowed reordering rule which causes the race condition in the OP's post:

> **8.2.3.4 Loads May Be Reordered with Earlier Stores to Different 
>   Locations**

On the other hand, if the original order of the instructions was switched:

```
shared variables
x = 0, y = 0

Core 1       Core 2
r1 = y;      r2 = x;
x = 1;       y = 1;
```

In this case, processor guarantees that `r1 = 1` and `r2 = 1` situation is not allowed (due to *8.2.3.3 Stores Are Not Reordered With Earlier Load* guarantee), meaning that those instructions would never be reordered in individual cores.

To compare this with different architectures, check out this article: [Memory Ordering in Modern Microprocessors](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/8211?page=0,1). You can see that Itanium (IA-64) does even more reordering than the IA-32 architecture:

[image: Possible CPU reorderings for various architectures]

Comment: That is possible. So the first operation is to change variable with constant. And second is to get value of variable and set to r[x]. So probably it will try to get variable value in the same time of performing first operation.

Comment: The compiler can also be the culprit, c.f. 'How to Miscompile Programs with "Benign" Data Races' - http://www.usenix.org/events/hotpar11/tech/final_files/Boehm.pdf.

Comment: @Brian: While interesting, a lot of the examples in that paper are false (not valid transformations the compiler can make) for C/POSIX due to signal handling semantics, especially if the elided code contains calls to `sigprocmask`.

Answer (score 3):

On processors with a weaker memory consistency model (such as SPARC, PowerPC, Itanium, ARM, etc.), the above condition can take place because of a lack of enforced cache-coherency on writes without an explicit memory barrier instruction.  So basically `Core1` sees the write on `x` before `y`, while `Core2` sees the write on `y` before `x`.  A full fence instruction wouldn't be required in this case ... basically you would only need to enforce write or release semantics with this scenario so that all writes are committed and visible to all processors before reads take place on those variables that have been written to.  Processor architectures with strong memory consistency models like x86 typically make this unnecessary, but as Groo points out, the compiler itself could re-order the operations.  You can use the `volatile` keyword in C and C++ to prevent the re-ordering of operations by the compiler within a given thread.  That is not to say that `volatile` will create thread-safe code that manages the visibility of reads and writes between threads ... a memory barrier would be required that.  So while the use of `volatile` can still create unsafe threaded code, within a given thread it will enforce sequential consistency at the complied machine-code level.

Comment: the *CPU* could reorder instructions too (while keeping cache coherency with respect to the new ordering).

Comment: Volatile won't prevent reorders, except on older compilers that used "volatile" as a keyword to completely disable the optimizer. You need a memory fence instruction.

Comment: If `volatile` didn't prevent compiler re-ordering within a given thread, then it would be absolutely pointless for use in memory-mapped I/O ... the compiler would still reorder the reads and writes, and you would get all sorts of undefined hardware behavior.  The `volatile` keyword does not prevent CPU reordering of instructions, nor does it enforce the visibility of reads and writes between threads ... that requires a memory barrier ... but it does prevent the compiler itself from reordering the operations within a given thread as defined in the source-code.

Answer (score 2):

#### This is why some say: [Threads Considered Harmful](http://radar.oreilly.com/archives/2007/01/threads-conside.html)

The problem is that neither thread enforces any ordering between its two statements, because they are not inter-dependent.

- The compiler knows that *x* and *y* are not aliased, and so it is not required to order the operations.
- The CPU knows that *x* and *y* are not aliased, so it may reorder them for speed. A good example of when this happens is when the CPU detects an opportunity for [write combining](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-combining). It may merge one write with another if it can do so without violating its coherency model.

The mutual dependency looks odd but it's really no different than any other race condition. Directly writing shared-memory-threaded code is quite difficult, and that's why parallel languages and message-passing parallel frameworks have been developed, in order to isolate the parallel hazards to a small kernel and remove the hazards from the applications themselves.