# Effect/Fullfillment of std::memory_order_* on x86(-64)

Tags: c++11, x86, x86-64, intel, memory-barriers

I have the following code:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <atomic>

void myAtomicStore(std::atomic<int32_t>& i, const int32_t v) {
    i.store(v, std::memory_order_release);
}

int myAtomicLoad(std::atomic<int32_t>& i, const int32_t v) {
    return i.load(std::memory_order_acquire);
}
```

And (according to [this](https://godbolt.org/g/GWZdrM)) GCC 8.1 translated it (for x86_64) into:

```
myAtomicStore(std::atomic<int>&, int):
        mov     DWORD PTR [rdi], esi
        ret
myAtomicLoad(std::atomic<int>&, int):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        ret
```

I wonder how the `mov`'s instructions can make all the writes to memory prior to `myAtomicStore()` become visible to another thread when it calls `myAtomicLoad()` on the same variable (or memory location) -- guaranteed by C++ standard.

I skimmed [Intel's manual](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf); and I don't see anything obvious.

Thanks!

Comment: You don't have *any other code*. Vacuously it is not running out-of-order

Comment: @Caleth: that's not the reason (except vs. compile-time reordering).  release stores apply to stores in the calling function, too.  The reason is that x86's strong memory model makes every store a release store, and every load an acquire load, so the compiler doesn't need any extra instructions.  http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/.  See also (http://preshing.com/20120515/memory-reordering-caught-in-the-act/. Looking for a duplicate Q&A; IIRC some quote Intel's memory ordering rules from the manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does it make any sense to use the LFENCE instruction on x86/x86\_64 processors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-the-lfence-instruction-on-x86-x86-64-processors)

Comment: The top answer [on that duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/) quotes Intel's SDM section 8.2.2, with the memory-ordering rules that disallow all reordering other than StoreLoad.  See also [Atomic operations, std::atomic<> and ordering of writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394427), and [Race condition on x86](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6623662), and [Does an x86 CPU reorder instructions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50310563), and the memory-ordering links in the x86 tag wiki: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the links.  I think I got it -- x86 doesn't allow CPU to reorder writes (with some exceptions mentioned in your last [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20316124/does-it-make-any-sense-to-use-the-lfence-instruction-on-x86-x86-64-processors)); hence, a series of simple `mov` has already "fulfilled" the guarantee mentioned in C++ standard.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, normal loads/stores have `acquire` and `release` semantics, but not `seq_cst`.  For that you need `mfence`, or preferably `xchg [mem], eax` to do a sequential-release store.  (And of course RMW operations are always seq_cst on x86 at least vs. runtime reordering (compile time reordering is still possible for mo_relaxed).  See [Can num++ be atomic for 'int num'?](//stackoverflow.com/q/39393850): you need `lock add` on a multicore system.)

Comment: @PeterCordes While you've already answered this question, note that the top answer on that possible duplicate is mostly incorrect.

Comment: @HadiBrais: hmm, yeah [Does x86-SSE-instructions have an automatic release-acquire order?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27302931) which quotes the same stuff without making false claims about `lfence + sfence` might be a better dup target.

Comment: @HadiBrais: I edited the accepted answer on the first question I linked, because it's maybe a better dup target for this question.

Comment: @PeterCordes The link you added is pretty much the most useful thing in the answer (specifically your answer there). Regarding the other [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19093137/does-x86-sse-instructions-have-an-automatic-release-acquire-order/27302931#27302931), only a little better, but still imprecise/incomplete because it does not talk about atomicity. Is there any answer on SO that clearly and precisely explains when and why x86 instructions have acquire and/or release semantics?...

Comment: ...Even Preshing's [article](http://preshing.com/20120913/acquire-and-release-semantics/) seems to only vaguely say `*usually*, every load on x86/64 already implies acquire semantics and every store implies release semantics. This is why x86/64 is *often* said to be strongly ordered`. (emphasis mine).

Comment: @PeterCordes I have spent few hours on some of your links...still can't finish all.  All I can say -- nice answers!  Thanks for sharing.  (Continue reading)