# How is it possible to return a reference via auto return type?

Tags: c++, auto, return-by-reference

I have a function `auto function(...)`. Is it possible to return a reference from it?

I *think* using a reference wrapper (`std::ref`?) would be the right thing to do, but I didn't really get how it works and is used, so please be so kind a write a short explanation.

I am aware of the dangers of returning references, but in my case it would make things easier if I could.

Comment: What do you want to return a reference to?  Do note returning a reference to a function local object is very, very bad.

Comment: Are you asking if you can return-by-reference when using `auto`? If so, then yes, you can. `auto` can be used in conjunction with specifiers and declarators.

Comment: @NathanOliver: OTOH, `operator[ ]` generally does return a reference.

Comment: @MSalters Not to a function local object.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Of course, but take `std::vector::operator[ ]` or `std::map`  as examples of why it's generally safe.

Comment: I never said anything to say it wasn't.  I said *returning a reference to a function local object is very, very bad*.  There is nothing misleading or incorrect with that.  I never said returning a reference from a function was bad.

Comment: @NathanOliver As stated, I am aware of the dangers. If you want the details: I either want to return `QList<int>` or `T&`. A `QList<T>&`is provided via parameter to the function, so it's not function local.

Comment: You can't use auto return type to return different things from a function.  All returns must return the same thing(possibly things that are all implicitly convertible to the same type,  Not 100% sure if that will work)

Comment: @NathanOliver Thanks for stating that! I didn't know that before and tried to create a function with different return types depending on configuration set in the parameters. With only one return type possible, `auto&` is a working answer to my question and I accepted it.

Comment: A good use case is the [Meyers singleton pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17712001/671509) which is essentially the example given in [@Bathsheba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38660144/671509).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, use `auto&`, much like as you would in a `for` loop if you were too busy to write out the type explicitly and didn't want to take value copies:

```
auto& nearly_ub() {
    static int foo;
    return foo;
}
```

but beware the *dangling* reference possibility.

Comment: Upvoted for understanding that the asker wants to not specify the return type.

Comment: I doubt OP asked how to change signature to return only references

Comment: @Slava You are correct. Depending on a specified parameter, I either want to returm `int` or `QList<T>&`. The given answer sadly does not match my requirement.

Comment: Edit: I meant `QList<int>` and `T&`. (My function is actually a template.)

Comment: @Bathsheba Accepted answer because it is not possible to achieve what I wanted to achieve (different return types via `auto`) and `auto&` works fine if you stick to one return type.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you can set `decltype(auto)` as the return type.

```
decltype(auto) nearly_ub() {
    static int foo;
    return foo;
}
```

See
https://stackoverflow.com/a/69233089/1414763