# C++ - auto return reference and non reference type

Tags: c++, reference, auto, rvalue, lvalue

When writing a function with `auto` return type we can use `constexpr if` to return different types.

```
auto myfunc()
{
   constexpr if (someBool)
   {
      type1 first = something;
      return first;
   }
   else
   {
      type2 second = somethingElse;
      return second;
   }
}
```

However, I'm struggling to work out how to make just one of the types a reference. It seems like the following code still returns an r-value for both branches

```
auto myfunc()
{
   constexpr if (someBool)
   {
      type1 &first = refToSomething;
      return first;
   }
   else
   {
      type2 second = somethingElse;
      return second;
   }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? Google isn't revealing much as there are so many tutorials on more general use of auto and return by reference. In my particular case the function is a class method and I want to either return a reference to member variable or a view of an array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `auto` will never be a reference. You need `decltype(auto)` instead, and also put the return value inside parentheses:

```
decltype(auto) myfunc()
{
   if constexpr (someBool)
   {
      type1 &first = refToSomething;
      return (first);
   }
   else
   {
      type2 second = somethingElse;
      return second;
   }
}
```