# C++ singleton wrapper for a STL container

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton, containers, constexpr

I am working in a C++11 solution, for Linux (Ubuntu 14.04; then I should need to migrate it to REL). I am using g++4.8 compiler (and I should probably be required to compile using Intel compiler).

But, please, focus on C++11 / Ubuntu 14.04 / g++4.8.

There are lots of `Singleton` implementations in the Web.

But it has been hard (and without success...) for me finding something like this:

1. **Ideal solution:**
   A generic (`template`) `Singleton`, from where I can inherit my classes which contain `STL containers`.
2. **Acceptable solution:**
   An "ad hoc" `Singleton` for each class with `STL containers`.
3. **"May be" possible solution:**
   I am aware of the discussions about `const` and `constexpr` vs `Singleton`. But my managers are quite outdated. And they want a `Singleton` solution. But I think if I can provide a solution using `const` / `constexpr` would be acceptable.

**Problem:** The found solutions let me have a `Singleton`. But this `Singleton` not only avoid creating new instances of the class (which is my goal: only one instance), but also avoid inserting new elements in the `STL containers` (this is not desired at all).

So, I am looking for a **`Singleton + STL containers` implementation:**

- which limits the created instances to only one.
- which lets me add as many elements as I want in the `queue, vector, set, map, list, array`, and so forth, containers which belongs to the unique created object.

Comment: I did not quite understand the limitations of the singleton classes which you found online. You should post the code that you tried or may be provide a c++ "pseudo" code that shows how you want it to work.

Comment: Not sure what you want, but this maybe a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton?rq=1

Comment: "*but also avoid inserting new elements in the STL containers*" That isn't necessary, it is probably because you decided to code it that way.

Comment: It is really not clear to me, what you want to do and I also don't see the connection between singleton and `const`. Please give a (pseudo-) code example of what you want to achieve.