# C++ Difficulty Creating Instance of Class within Singleton Class

Tags: c++, class, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have a fairly good template (as in snippet of code) I pull out whenever I need a singleton class.  I am now trying to apply it within my project to allow me to control a single instance of a web server.  I can make a web server without encasing it in my class.  When I try to encase it within the class I'm apparently too unskilled to pull it off.

I've tried the obvious Googling and searching here.  I've read relevant posts.  I am sure this does not mean I have a unique problem, just that I've not figured out the right way to fix it.  Here's what I am working with:

webserver.h:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <FS.h>

class WebServer {
    private:
        // Singleton Declarations
        static bool instanceFlag;
        static WebServer *single;
        WebServer() {}
        // Other Declarations
        FS *filesystem;
        ESP8266WebServer server();
        String getContentType(String);
        bool handleFileRead(String);

    public:
        // Singleton Declarations
        static WebServer* getInstance();
        ~WebServer() {instanceFlag = false;}
        // Other Declarations
        void initialize(int);
        void handleLoop();
};
```

webserver.cpp:

```cpp
#include "webserver.h"

bool WebServer::instanceFlag = false;
WebServer* WebServer::single = NULL;

WebServer* WebServer::getInstance() {
    if(!instanceFlag) {
        single = new WebServer();
        instanceFlag = true;
        return single;
    } else {
        return single;
    }
}

void WebServer::initialize (int port) {
    ESP8266WebServer server(port);
    FS *filesystem;
    filesystem->begin();

    Serial.print("Open: http://");
    Serial.print(WiFi.hostname().c_str());
    Serial.println(".local");

    server.onNotFound([]() {
        if (!single->handleFileRead(single->server.uri())) {
            single->server.send(404, "text/plain", "404: File not found.");
        }
    });

    server.begin();
    Serial.print("HTTP server started on port ");
    Serial.print(port);
    Serial.println(".");
}

String WebServer::getContentType(String filename) {
    if (single->server.hasArg("download")) {
        return "application/octet-stream";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".htm")) {
        return "text/html";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".html")) {
        return "text/html";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".css")) {
        return "text/css";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".js")) {
        return "application/javascript";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".png")) {
        return "image/png";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".gif")) {
        return "image/gif";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".jpg")) {
        return "image/jpeg";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".ico")) {
        return "image/x-icon";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".xml")) {
        return "text/xml";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".pdf")) {
        return "application/x-pdf";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".zip")) {
        return "application/x-zip";
    } else if (filename.endsWith(".gz")) {
        return "application/x-gzip";
    } else {
       return "text/plain"; 
    }
}

bool WebServer::handleFileRead(String path) {
    Serial.println("handleFileRead: " + path);
    if (path.endsWith("/")) {
        path += "index.htm";
    }
    String contentType = getContentType(path);
    String pathWithGz = path + ".gz";
    if (filesystem->exists(pathWithGz) || filesystem->exists(path)) {
        if (filesystem->exists(pathWithGz)) {
            path += ".gz";
        }
        File file = filesystem->open(path, "r");
        single->server.streamFile(file, contentType);
        file.close();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void WebServer::handleLoop() {
    single->server.handleClient();
}
```

The errors I am getting are all similar to the following:

```
src\webserver.cpp: In member function 'bool WebServer::handleFileRead(String)':
src\webserver.cpp:81:23: error: 'WebServer::single->WebServer::server' does not have class type
         single->server.streamFile(file, contentType);
```

I get the idea of "does not have a class type", I just have no idea what it means here.  In my mind, "single" is a pointer to the class so I'm unclear what that reference is not working.

Obviously, there are ample examples out there how to do a web server without encapsulating it.  Other things I need to do for this project lend itself to creating that requirement.

Comment: FWIW, if you are going to make a singleton, you should use a [Meyers' Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton)

Comment: `WebServer::server` sure looks a lot like a function: `ESP8266WebServer server();` You sure you want those brackets there, or should we close this as a typo?

Comment: @user4581301, not sure what you mean exactly.  The only brackets I see are in the server.onNotFound handler and when I remove that I have the same issue. I'm sure the 'WebServer::single->WebServer::server' part is screaming at me with the information I need, I just don't understand it I guess.

Comment: Thank you for the reference @NathanOliver. I'll have a look although I suspect I'll make the same mistake instantiating/using the lib class.

Comment: Apologies for not being clear enough. The brackets at the end of `ESP8266WebServer server();` accidentally declared a function rather than defining a variable, leading to the error message much later. A function is not a class, so you cant use `.` to access a member. One thing you're going to find in programming is that the actual mistake is often nowhere near the crash site.

Comment: Got it, thank you @user4581301.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistake in your code.
In `webserver.h`:

```
...
private:
    // Singleton Declarations
    static bool instanceFlag;
    static WebServer *single;
    WebServer() {}
    // Other Declarations
    FS *filesystem;
    ESP8266WebServer *server; // <--- remove the parentheses and make it a pointer
    String getContentType(String);
    bool handleFileRead(String);
...
```

In `webserver.cpp`:

In `WebServer::initialize` I am guessing you want to initialize the class `server` and `filesystem` not locals, so it should probably look like this:

```
void WebServer::initialize (int port) {
    server = new ESP8266WebServer(port);
    filesystem = new FS();
    ...
}
```

And now everywhere you use the server you have to use the `->` operator.
For example:

```
void WebServer::handleLoop() {
    single->server->handleClient();
}
```

Please keep in mind that `server` and `filesystem` objects have to be deleted to avoid memory leaks.

**EDIT:**

You get the new error because FS has no constructor without arguments.
FS's constructor looks like this: `FS(FSImplPtr impl) : _impl(impl) { }`, [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/FS.h#L36) you can see that FSImplPtr is a typedef for `std::shared_ptr<FileImpl>`, so you need to provide this as a parameter.

It works your way, because SPIFFS's existence is declared [here](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/FS.h#L250) and is of type FS.

If you want to use `SPIFFS`, you have to use it like this: `filesystem = &SPIFFS;`, not like you mentioned in the comments (`FS* filesystem = &SPIFFS;`) because your way creates a new temporary variable named `filesystem`, and probably you expect to initiate the `filesystem` in the class, not a local one.

Comment: Thank you for the concise review of the issues as you see them @N Alex.  I'll give that a go.

Comment: So that was definitely my issue with declaring the ESP8266WebServer - not sure how I overlooked the () there.  Maybe if I pay attention to IntelliSense next time?  Now getting error in `WebServer::initialize` though: `src\webserver.cpp:18:25: error: no matching function for call to 'fs::FS::FS()'`  Not sure what's wrong with the statement `filesystem = new FS();`?  I'm sincerely hoping this is not another stupid error which I've made.  I changed it to FS* filesystem = &SPIFFS; - testing now to see if that behaves how I expect.

Comment: So you got me past the error I posted -  Thank you!  Although I am curious why I need to declare FS as `FS* filesystem = &SPIFFS;` as well as instantiate the same way in `WebServer::initialize`?

Comment: @LCB please see my edit for an answer to your new error

Comment: I understand now, thank you so much for your help @N_Alex.