# MQTT publish exception(Access violation reading location)

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, c++17, mqtt

When I am publishing message via mqtt::publish(), I am getting below exception.

Exception thrown at 0x00007FF68471021C in xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000008

[image]

Part of code where I am publishing my message :

mqtt_client.h

```
class mqtt_client : public virtual mqtt::callback
{
private:    
    static const std::uint16_t                                      connect_timeout = 10000;
    static inline                                               mqtt_client *instance = nullptr;
    std::string                         uri;
        uint16_t                                                        mqtt_timeout;
        std::string                         client_id;
        std::string                         topic;
        std::string                         topic_in;
        std::string                         topic_out;
    std::mutex                          transmit_queue_mutex;
    std::atomic_bool                                            transmit_in_progress{ false };
    std::atomic_bool                                            connection_established{ false }, connection_in_progress{ false };
    std::queue<std::string>                                     transmit_queue;
    std::unique_ptr<mqtt::async_client>                             client;
public:
        mqtt_client();
    ~mqtt_client();
    inline const static uint8_t                                     qos = 2;
    static mqtt_client                                              *get_instance(void);
    bool                                                            connect(void);
    bool                                                            send_data(const std::string& data);
    mqtt_client(mqtt_client &&obj) = delete;
    mqtt_client& operator=(const mqtt_client&) = delete;
    mqtt_client& operator=(mqtt_client&&) = delete;
};
```

mqtt_client.cpp

```
mqtt_client *mqtt_client::get_instance(void)
{
    try {
        if (mqtt_client::instance == nullptr)
            mqtt_client::instance = new mqtt_client();
        return mqtt_client::instance;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) {
        mqtt_client::instance = nullptr;
        return mqtt_client::instance;
    }
}

bool mqtt_client::connect(void)
{
    try 
    {
        this->client = std::make_unique<mqtt::async_client>(this->uri, this->client_id);
        this->client->set_callback(*this);
        mqtt::connect_options conn_opts;
        conn_opts.set_clean_session(false);
        conn_opts.set_will_message(mqtt::message(this->topic_out, "Disconnected", 12));
        conn_opts.set_automatic_reconnect(true);
        mqtt::token_ptr connect_token = this->client->connect(conn_opts);
        connect_token->wait();
        return true;
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception& ex) 
    {
        std::string stre = std::string("Error in MQTT connection. Error : ") + ex.what() 
               + std::string(" [ ") + std::to_string(ex.get_reason_code()) + std::string(" ] ");
        LOGE << stre;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << " ["
            << ex.get_reason_code() << "]" << std::endl;
#endif 
        return false;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) 
    {
        std::string stre = std::string("Error while connecting to MQTT. Error : ") + ex.what();
        LOGE << stre;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cout << stre << std::endl;
#endif 
        return false;
    }
}

bool mqtt_client::send_data(const std::string& data)
{
    try {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock { this->transmit_queue_mutex };
            this->transmit_queue.push(data);
        }
        if(not this->transmit_in_progress.load())
            this->transmit_message();
        return true;
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception& ex) 
    {
        std::string stre = std::string("Error in sending data. Error : ") + ex.what()
                + std::string(" [ ") + std::to_string(ex.get_reason_code()) + std::string(" ] ");
        LOGE << stre;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << " ["
            << ex.get_reason_code() << "]" << std::endl;
#endif 
        return false;
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex)
    {
        std::string stre = std::string("Error in sending data. Error : ") + ex.what();
        LOGE << stre;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cout << stre << std::endl;
#endif 
        return false;
    }
}

void mqtt_client::transmit_message(void)
{
    try {
        std::string data;
        {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock{ this->transmit_queue_mutex };
                if (this->transmit_queue.empty())
                        return;
                data = this->transmit_queue.front();
        }
        mqtt::message_ptr msg = mqtt::make_message(this->topic_out, data.data(), data.length(), mqtt_client::qos, false);
        this->transmit_in_progress.store(true);
        this->client->publish(msg);
    }
    catch (const mqtt::exception& ex) 
    {
        std::string stre = std::string("Error in transmitting message. Error : ") + ex.what()
                + std::string(" [ ") + ex.get_reason_code_str() + std::string(" ] ");
        LOGE << stre;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << " ["
            << ex.get_reason_code_str() << "]" << std::endl;
#endif 
    }
    catch (const std::exception& ex) 
    {
        std::string stre = std::string("Error in transmitting message. Error : ") + ex.what();
        LOGE << stre;
#ifdef _DEBUG
        std::cout << stre << std::endl;
#endif 
    }
}
```

This error is occurring in Windows Visual Studio.
I am using same code in one project written using Netbean IDE for linux(Raspberry Pi). mqtt is installed in Raspberry using `apt get` .There it is working without any issue.

OS : Windows 10 Home

Bit : x64

Visual Studio : Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017

vcpkg : paho-mqttpp3

Comment: It seems you are dereferencing `nullptr` somewhere. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: 1) `this` could be invalid.  2) `client` could be invalid.  If it's `this` being invalid, then none of what is in the code you show is valid. -- *There it is working without and issue.* -- That doesn't mean that the bug doesn't exist in those other environments -- it's just that it may not have been exposed (yet).  Once you figure out this error, you may have to go to those other environments and make the fix there also.

Comment: @MikeCAT I have uploaded code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are right, once error is figured out I will change my other environments. Can you please guide me where this issue is occurring.

Comment: @S.K. `mqtt_client::get_instance` is not thread-safe.

Comment: @S.K. -- I made the comment on the thread-safety of `get_instance`, since you are using threading in the code.  The reason why `get_instance` is not thread safe is that if two or more threads are calling `get_instance`, there is a chance that multiple threads can enter the `if (mqtt_client::instance == nullptr)`  check, thus creating a race condition.  Either use a [Meyers` singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton) , or no singleton and use a different approach.

Comment: Also, if indeed the issue is with `get_instance`, then this may explain the reason why it seemingly works in the other environments when it is actually not thread-safe.

Comment: Problem got resolved. Thank You @PaulMcKenzie for helping to resolve the issue.