# C++: Static member function returning an object of self static for a class with private constructor

Tags: c++, static, singleton, static-members, static-functions

I've a C++ snippet as below. The "getInstance()" function is trying to return a static object of the same class "CAbc". This class has a private constructor so that objects of this class can't be created.

While calling this function in main(), like in below snippet, the returned object is not being collected anywhere in main() using any reference.

I'm trying to understand the below 2 points:

- What is this way of creating a static object & returning it from
  within the static member function of same class type ? There is no
  object created when a constructor is private. Then how does this
  object return work here ?
- And how does this way of not collecting the object in main() work ?

This is being called in the main() function.

```
class CAbc
{
private:
CAbc() {} // HAS A PRIVATE CONSTRUCTOR
.....
public:
static CAbc& getInstance()
    {
        static CAbc _self;
            return _self;
    }
    // what does this returning a static self object mean in C++ ?
}

main()
{
CAbc::getInstance();
// not collectig this anywhere ?
}
```

Comment: `This class has a private constructor so that objects of this class can't be created.` and `There is no object created when a constructor is private.`: This is wrong. The class itself (or, methods of the class) can call private methods, which means, the static class method _can_ (and does) create a instance of the class.

Comment: No object is being returned by `getInstance`, instead a reference to the object is being returned.

Comment: And for your other question, it's not an error not to 'collect' a return value. There's nothing to work, the returned value (or reference) is just thrown away. You might ask what the point is, but that's a different question.

Comment: FYI, What you have is called a [Meyer's singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton/17713799)

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @tkausi says, the static member function can create an object, as it is a *member* (thus having access to private methods.)

What this code does is having an instance of the class, only one object (`_self`) and returning it for use.

Why nobody gets the return value? Because the call is there only to create the instance. If you don't call the function no `_self` object will be created.

```
class CAbc
{
private:
    CAbc() { cout << "creating" << endl; }
public:
static CAbc& getInstance()
    {
        static CAbc _self;
            return _self;
    }
};

int main() {
    cout << "Begin" << endl;

    //CAbc::getInstance();
}
```

With the call to `getInstance` commented out you won't see the "creating" output.

If you uncomment the call, you'll see:

```
Begin
creating
```

Once created, the function will always return the same object.