# Android JNI crashes (SIGABRT)

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, java-native-interface

I have an Android Kotlin application that calls a simple JNI function, the latter calling a C++ singleton.
There is a crash (SIGABRT) when I call the JNI function. I can't see what is wrong...

Kotlin code :

```
stopProcessing() // Calls stopProcessing JNI function
```

JNI code :

```
extern "C"
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL
Java_com_tb_of_1ir_MainActivity_stopProcessing(JNIEnv *env, jobject thiz) {
    static auto a = MySingleton::get();
    a->stopProcessing();
}
```

C++ code :

```
[[noreturn]] void stopProcessing() {
}
```

There is nothing in the C++ code for now, but even if something inside (anything) there is the same problem.

Thanks !

Edit :

The singleton code :

```
#include "MySingleton.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <signal.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <bitset>

class MySingleton {

private:
    static MySingleton *singleton;
    explicit MySingleton() {
        src_string = "The default string value";
    }

public:
    static MySingleton *get()  {
        if (singleton == nullptr)
            singleton = new MySingleton();
        return singleton;
    }

    bool MySingletonStarted = false;
    bool stop = false;

    std::string dest_string, src_string;

    [[noreturn]] void startProcessing() {
        stop = false;

        MySingletonStarted = true;
        while(!stop) {
            dest_string = src_string;
        }
    }

    void stopProcessing() {
    }

};

MySingleton *MySingleton::singleton = nullptr;
```

Comment: *I can't see what is wrong...* -- `a->stopProcessing();` -- We have no idea if `a` is a valid pointer.

Comment: There are a lot of other functions that work. a is valid in all other cases. There is another method named "startProcessing()" and it works.

Comment: `[[noreturn]]`- _"...The __behavior is undefined__ if the function with this attribute actually returns...."_ https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/noreturn

Comment: Let's see the function `MySingleton::get()`.  Also, just because something "works" doesn't mean there isn't an already existing bug.  But what else would cause that issue, unless `a` is pointing to somewhere invalid?

Comment: Here is the singleton code (very basic) : https://pastebin.com/ve2YUrpS

Comment: @KotlinIsland It would be better if you posted that code here.  Given that, the singleton is not thread safe.  If two or more threads are able to call that `get()` function, then that is definitely an issue.

Comment: So do you mean I have to make it thread safe ? I've just added the code here in the original question.

Comment: I have not used Kotlin, but definitely, if you can determine that there is a potential for two or more threads to call `get()`, then yes, you must make it thread safe.

Comment: I sometimes get SIGBUS errors too... Ok, thanks I'll try to make that...

Comment: Richard Critten  has given the solution indirectly. I've removed the [[noreturn]] statement and everything runs fine now !!! Add an answer and I'll accept it ;) THANKS (to both of you) !!!!!!!!

Comment: @KotlinIsland [See the Meyer's singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton).  That is thread-safe as per C++ 11.  The only issue is that you cannot rely on deterministic destruction of the static instance (shouldn't be a problem if you don't care what happens at the close of a program, and you haven't written code that relies on the destruction of the singleton instance).

Comment: Yes I've found this link too, but thanks. I've found the solution to my problem, that was because of the [[noreturn]] statement (I added it because of the IDE warnings). I have removed that and now things are fine. I'll check for thread safety too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to remove the [[noreturn]] statement in the C++ singleton class.

Thanks to Richard Critten who commented (Add an answer and I'll accept it).