# Why static instance constructor not called at second time?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code

```
#include <iostream>

class my_class {
    public:
    static my_class& factory(int val) {
        static my_class instance{val};
        return instance;
    }
    private:
    my_class(int value) {
        std::cout<<value<<std::endl;
    };
};


int main() {
    auto& i77 = my_class::factory(77); // call #1
    auto& i1 = my_class::factory(1);  // call #2
    return 0;
}
```

The output is 77. On the call #2 constructor isn't called.

I understand what happens in call #1. Compiler allocates memory for instance at compile time and calls constructor on enetering `my_class::factory(77);`

But what happens on call #2? Why constructor isn't called? Is this behavior standard?

Comment: Because it is static. You answered your own question

Comment: Static objects are instantiated only once. Your factory simply returns a reference to the same object each time.

Comment: Yes, it works as intended: on the second call, the same instance is reused.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Static local variables are created and initialized on the first call to the function. Then they have a life-time of the remaining program, and exists for all calls to the function.

Comment: It's not a factory, it's a singleton similar to one described by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton

Comment: because static object (in a function) is somehow the same as a global object, it is stored the "rw--" segment of the module, and they are initialized at loading time just before give the control to your user code. compiler will ignore the declaration and initialization for static object when compile the function.