# Is Singleton with static unique_ptr a good practice

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I work in a project where Singletons are usually implemented like this:

```cpp
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& get();
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;

    // Used for unit tests
    static void reset();

protected:
    static std::unique_ptr<Singleton>& instance();
};
```

```cpp
unique_ptr<Singleton>& Singleton::instance()
{
    static unique_ptr<Singleton> instance;
    return instance;
}

Singleton& Singleton::get()
{
    auto& instance = instance();
    if (!instance) {
        // We cannot use make_unique<T>() as constructor is private
        instance = unique_ptr<Singleton>(new Singleton());
    }
    return *instance;
}

void Singleton::reset() { instance().reset(); }
// Private constructor
Singleton::Singleton() {}
```

No thread safety is required here.
Is there any advantages of using a `static unique_ptr` ?
What are the consequences of creating the Singleton with `unique_ptr<T>(new T())` ?

Since our Singletons can carry (some) global state, a public reset() was implemented for testing purposes, is it the only way and can this be improved ?

I have found some examples of C++ singleton design patterns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern/1008289#1008289).
But never implemented with unique_ptr like mine.

Comment: What is gain of having `std::unique_ptr<Singleton>& instance();` instead: `Singleton& instance();`? Are you planing to allow external code to destroy instance of `Singelton`?

Comment: If you are going to use `unique_ptr`, why not declare and initialize it in `get()` and get rid of `instance()`? `Singleton& Singleton::get() { static unique_ptr<Singleton> instance(new Singleton()); return *instance; }` For that matter, why use a `unique_ptr` at all? Do you really need to `reset()` a singleton? The typical (and thread-safe) implementation is to just use a `static` object, eg: `Singleton& Singleton::get() { static Singleton instance; return instance; }`

Comment: I can't think of any benefit of `unique_ptr` here. All this implementation has done is reduce the thread safety. `Singleton& Singleton::get() { static Singleton instance; return instance; }` is more thread safe and has the same result. Thread safety may not be important now, but it doesn't hurt either.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, when a `create()` and `get()` is needed (e.g creation with parameters) `instance()` is just a shortcut. I apologize, it's not very useful in my example.

Comment: There is no need to use a `unique_ptr` for a singleton.  Use a [Meyers' Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton) instead

Comment: How should I deal with the `reset()` function with a "Meyers' Singleton" static reference ? The tricks here is that you can destroy the singleton and create a new one.

Comment: @Moulagaufres if you *always* create new one after destroy, then yes you can do it with just a reference.

Comment: *How should I deal with the reset()?* -- If you have non-const reference or pointer you can always call destructor and in-place new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are exists two ways to reset Meyer's singleton:

```
#include <new>

class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& instance() {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;

    // Option 1 - easy and convinient if Singleton is copyable or movable
    void reset1() {
        *this = {};
    }
    // Option 2 - works always
    void reset2() {
        this->~Singleton();
        new (this) Singleton;
    }

private:
    Singleton() {}
};
```

2nd option is basically doing exactly what you are doing with releasing/creating `std::unique_ptr`, except without deallocation/allocation of storage.

Comment: I have a `this is unavailable for static member functions` error

Comment: This has another advantage over the unique_ptr method: If somebody holds a reference to the singleton (which seems a sufficiently sensible thing to do), their reference won't be invalidated by the `reset()`.

Comment: @Moulagaufres If you want `reset()` to be `static` then use `&instance()` instead of `this`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You'd get lazy instance creation if you use a pointer as opposed to a reference.
2. If the `reset()` is a logical reset, you won't need a pointer, a reference would do but, if the requirement is that of a memory reset, you'll need it.
3. Since the lifetime of the static singleton instance is the whole application lifetime, you don't need to care about the RAII benefit that you get with unique ptr.
4. But, you'd use `unique_ptr` to indicate exclusive ownership over the resource and some guidelines forbid using raw pointers for non-owning
5. The current code allows copying and moving of your instance, breaking the Singleton invariances.

Answer (score -1):

There is no need to use std::unique_ptr. Use references

```cpp
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton& instance();
    virtual ~Singleton() = default;

    // Used for unit tests
    void reset();
private:
    Singleton();
    int stuff;
};

Singleton& Singleton::instance()
{
    static Singleton instance;
    return instance;
}

void Singleton::reset() { stuff = 0; }

// Private constructor
Singleton::Singleton() {}
```

Comment: TY but this does not makes sense for me: `void Singleton::reset() { instance().reset(); }` as we are not resetting the unique_ptr

Comment: True. I have changed the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Note that this design is dominated by your requirement for a `reset` function. This prevents you from using certain Singleton implementations, like e.g. [Meyer's Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17712001/how-is-meyers-implementation-of-a-singleton-actually-a-singleton).

In general you would want a singleton implementation to not allow the implementation of a `reset` method, because now your singleton is not really a singleton anymore. But it might of course make sense to "water down" the singleton for testing purposes.

If multithreading-safety is not a concern, your singleton implementation is overly complicated and could be reduced to:

```cpp
class Singleton
{
public:
  static Singleton& get() {
    if (!mInstance) {
        mInstance = std::unique_ptr<Singleton>(new Singleton());
    }
    return *mInstance;
  }
  
  static void reset() { mInstance.reset(); }

private:
  static inline std::unique_ptr<Singleton> mInstance{};
};
```