# How does singleton instance implementation in C++ does not leak memory?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management, singleton, implementation

I'm studying about singletons in design patterns and I saw this singleton implementation and I tested it with `fsanitize=address`, because there is no `delete` keyword even though there is a `new` keyword being use I suspect that this is an incomplete implementation and therefore has memory leak, but after running the program it doesn't seems to have one? why is that? we are allocating new memory for `*singleton` so it should be a dangling pointer?

```cpp
class Singleton {
    public:
        static Singleton& instance() {
            static Singleton* singleton = new Singleton();
            return *singleton;
        }

        void set_data(int value) { data = value; }
        int get_data() { return data; }
    private:
        Singleton() : data(0) {}
        ~Singleton() {}
        int data;    
};
```

How come this singleton implementation does not leak memory in C++?

If I rewrite this singleton class into something like this:

```cpp
class Singleton {
    public:
        static Singleton& instance() {
            static Singleton* singleton;
            
            if (singleton == nullptr) {
                singleton = new Singleton();
            }

            return *singleton;
        }

        void set_data(int value) { data = value; }
        int get_data() { return data; }
    private:
        Singleton() : data(0) {}
        ~Singleton() { delete this; }
        int data;    
};
```

What would be the difference?

Comment: *"we are allocating new memory for *singleton so it should be a dangling pointer?"* -- A dangling pointer occurs after the memory it points to is deleted/destructed, which is sort of the opposite of what you mean.

Comment: Singletons are not much more than glorified global variables. I'd advise to avoid them. They cause more problems than they solve in the long run.

Comment: Since `singleton` refers to the dynamically allocated object until the program terminates, there is no leak.     As JaMiT noted, a dangling pointer is something different - you're conflating two different concepts.   On modern operating systems, all memory resources that have not been released (e.g. `new`d objects without a `delete`, statically allocated object destructed) are reclaimed as the running process ends.

Comment: BTW:  doing `delete this` in a destructor is bad practice, since it is effectively the destructor recursively calling itself on the same object, giving infinite recursion.

Comment: Usually you don't need `new` to create a singleton. Just `static Singleton singleton; return singleton;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come this singleton implementation does not leak memory in C++?

This singleton implementation does leak memory.

That said, the memory is leaked immediately before the program terminates, and thus the leak doesn't really matter. This is a common technique that can be used to speed up the termination time, as well as avoid certain rare cases of Static *Destruction* Order Fiasco.

> I tested it with fsanitize=address

Few points regarding this:

- Did you run with `ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1`? Address sanitizer does not do leak detection by default on all systems.
- Sanitizers don't generally guarantee to find bugs, so your test is not a proof that there is no leak.
- In this case, the non-detection might be intentional; but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that the initialization of `static` local variables takes place only once, not each time the function is entered.

```cpp
static Singleton& instance() {
    static Singleton* singleton = new Singleton(); // this runs only once, when the function
                                                   // is first entered
    return *singleton;
}
```

#### Is there a memory leak?

Knowing that `new Singleton()` runs only once, it still depends on your definition of "memory leak" whether you actually leak memory.
There are usually two schools of thought:

- Memory is leaked if it hasn't been freed by the time the program exists.
- Memory is leaked if it's no longer reachable by the time the program exits.

The memory allocated with `new Singleton` is still reachable when the program exists, namely through the pointer `singleton`, so it isn't a leak in the latter sense.
However, the memory isn't automatically freed through `delete`, so it is a memory leak in the former sense.

Note that leak detectors are usually going to classify these cases differently ("definitely lost" vs. "still reachable").

*See also: [Still Reachable Leak detected by Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3840582/5740428)*

#### Meyers' singleton

Note that there is a better implementatin of Meyer's singleton that doesn't suffer from any leak:

```cpp
static Singleton& instance() {
    static Singleton singleton; // don't make this a pointer
    return singleton;
}
```

*See also [How is Meyers' implementation of a Singleton actually a Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17712001/5740428)*