# Is it right to use the singleton pattern for implementing a configuration manager?

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a class which currently defines a static variables that stores several parameters list.

```
static list<shared_ptr<ParameterContainer> > _containers
```

These `ParameterContainers` should be accessible by different clients.

The `ParameterContainers` are created by the constructor of the class, which receives a path as input, reads values from XML files contained in the path and stores the new `ParameterContainers` in `_containers`. The constructor control that the files have not been already stored.

Clients can access, modify and save on the XML files the parameters values.
The variable `_containers` is protected by a mutex, which guarantee the correct shared access.

I think that having a central repository for this parameters is good, it avoids to loading it every time from a file. This is actually achieved by means of the static variable `_containers`.

I'm wondering if it would be better to implement the entire class a singleton and remove the keyword static from the variable `_containters`.

I read several discussions about the fact that the singleton could be an anti-pattern.
I would like to know a good reason for avoiding singleton in this case.

Comment: There could be a problem if multiple singletons are used and there are dependencies. E.g. depending on a logging singleton. It's difficult to ensure in which order they will be created and closed. This could lead to problems.

Comment: @AdamSangala: It's only a problem if the singleton relies on it's constructor to initialize its members. The typical implementation is to have a static pointer set to NULL (setting `static` variables to zero happens BEFORE constructors are called) to the instance of the singleton, and make the singleton into a functor. This means that the constructor for the singleton is called "manually" inside the functor, so it's safe.

Comment: I think you could use Scott Meyers implementation of Singleton in which "manual" instantiation is possible. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-singleton-pattern-thread-safe

Comment: That depends on your singleton religion.

Comment: @MatsPetersson The problem is with shutting down. Let's say you have 2 singletons A, and B, B uses A instance in it's destructor. (This is valid approach, let's say A is a logger) How do you ensure the order of destructors called for your singleton instances?

Comment: @AdamSangala: Then don't use the singleton's destructor to destroy the instance, just flush the file (if it's a logger) and leave the instance to be "leaked". Yes, it's ugly, but if you are using loggers in global objects destructors, then that's what you have to do.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Sure, the described is a flawed design. I was just trying to illustrate that singletons can get very ugly if there are dependencies.

Comment: @PlasmaHH : I am 100% in agreement with your statement. I undestand what you mean.