# static object vs singleton class object in c++?

Tags: c++, singleton

I just want to know when should I use singleton class over static object and vice versa. Because same can be used to have only one instance.
One reason I can guess about the storage difference in memory.
Is there any other reason to choose one over the other.

Comment: In many cases a singleton is in fact implemented as a class with a static variable. In a multithreaded environment i believe the current c++ standards do not ensure that implementation is valid.. in any other case you can use the "static" implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern

Comment: You _should_ not use either! If you _absolutely have to_ you are probably better off using a function local static object.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: a function local static object = Meyers' singleton. ;-)

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: `int& f() { static int rc{}; return rc; }` - this makes `int` a singleton of some sort...?!?

Comment: @DietmarKühl: yep. it's called "Meyers" after Scott Meyers. the main problem with it is that for class type it may be destroyed too soon, e.g. a logging facility releasing itself before some crucial stuff is logged after exit has been initiated. in c++03 it also had threading issues, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-singleton-pattern-thread-safe oh, thinking about it probably still has threading issues...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between a singleton and a static object is that the singleton guarantees that there can only be one instance of a particular class type, whereas a static object **is** only a single instance of a particular type.  This means that the fundamental difference is whether it makes sense for the **class** to have multiple instances or not.  For example, let's say that you have a factory that builds widgets.

```
class WidgetFactory {
    public:
        int numberOfWidgetsBuiltInTheWholeApplication();
            // returns number_of_widgets_built
        std::shared_ptr<Widget> build();
            // increments number_of_widgets_built
    private:
        size_t number_of_widgets_built;
};
```

Let's also assume that we want to guarantee that we can determine the number of Widgets that were created in the entire application, and enforcing that there is only one WidgetFactory is an easy way to do this.  This is where we would use a singleton.  If we were to just use a static object, like this:

```
WidgetFactory& theWidgetFactory()
{
    static WidgetFactory widget_factory;
    return widget_factory;
}
```

we would have no guarantee that `theWidgetFactory().numberOfWidgetsBuiltInTheWholeApplication()` was actually the real total, since someone else could come along and make their own WidgetFactory instance.

However, if we make WidgetFactory be a singleton, we now have that guarantee.  We could do that perhaps by making the constructors private:

```
class WidgetFactory {
    public:
        int numberOfWidgetsBuiltInTheWholeApplication();
        std::shared_ptr<Widget> build();
    private:
        WidgetFactory();
        WidgetFactory(const WidgetFactory &); // not implemented
        friend WidgetFactory& theWidgetFactory();
};
```

Now only `theWidgetFactory()` function is allowed to create the instance.  There are other ways that we could make `numberOfWidgetsBuiltInTheWholeApplication()` function properly without using a singleton, but perhaps in some situations that solution is more complicated or has other downsides.

Comment: Vaughn. If I want to restrict that only 5 objects can be created of this class. then what will be the approach?

Comment: @vivekjain:  One approach would be to have 5 friend functions, where each one returns one of the five instances.

Answer (score 1):

where only static initialization is involved, a global constant is ok. where dynamic initialization is involved, you want to avoid the [static initialization fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/static-init-order.html). hence if you must, singleton should be preferred.

however, *mutable* singletons are generally just global variables in disguise.

therefore, to the extent practically possible, avoid them.