# connect to database only one time using singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

I'm trying to connect to the database only one time by using singleton pattern, below is my implementation.

Will it guarantee that the `m_connector.connect();` is only called once?

Is using singleton the best solution?

```
class ConnectionManager
{
public:

  static ConnectionManager& getManager()
  {
    static ConnectionManager manager;
    return manager;
  }

  void reconnect();
  Connection getConnection();

private:
  ConnectionManager():m_connector("port")
  {
    m_connector.connect();
  };
  ConnectionManager(ConnectionManager const&);
  void operator=(ConnectionManager const&);

  Connector m_connector;
};
```

Comment: Do not use singletons.

Comment: Did you write any unit tests to determine if `connect` is called more than once? Did you refer to the C++ Standard to see what the lifetime of objects with static [storage duration](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration)?

Comment: _"Will it guarantee that the m_connector.connect(); is only called once?"_ Hmm, `void reconnect();` somehow hints it might be called multiple times.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that's used when the connection is lost and retrying to connect.

Comment: @user3828398 Well, I can't know without seeing what the implementation does. It's under your control, but the singleton pattern alone cannot guarantee this function is called more than once.

Comment: @WilliamKappler The constructor calls a member instances function, that's a big difference.

Comment: @user3828398 Are you actually worrying about thread safety? The pattern you use is guaranteed to be thread safe with the current standard.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are correct, I seem to have missed that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ so all threads share the same connectionmanager?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ and if I want each thread to have a separate connectionmanager, I need to use `thread_local` instead of `static`, right?

Comment: @user3828398 _"so all threads share the same connectionmanager? "_ Well, I don't know? That depends on your implementation. Currently it would be like that, yes.

Comment: @user3828398 _"I need to use thread_local instead of static, right?"_, well don't use a singleton then.

Answer (score 0):

> Will it guarantee that the `m_connector.connect();` only run once?

No.

The only fact that's guaranteed in that case of implementation (aka as [Scott Meyer's Singleton](http://www.aristeia.com/Papers/DDJ_Jul_Aug_2004_revised.pdf)) is that the constructor of `ConnectionManager` is called once and only once.

```
  static ConnectionManager& getManager()
  {
    static ConnectionManager manager;
    return manager;
  }
```

It will be called as soon `ConnectionManager::getManager();` is called the first time.

The constructor in turn calls `m_connector.connect()`

```
  ConnectionManager():m_connector("port")
  {
    m_connector.connect();
  };
```

There's no guarantee that

```
    m_connector.connect();
```

won't be called from any other parts of your code. The declaration of

```
  void reconnect();
```

even implies that somehow.

But well, it's all under your control.

If the constructor is the only function that calls `m_connector.connect();`, and you are worrying about [*thread safety*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-singleton-pattern-thread-safe), you shouldn't need to. It's guaranteed to be thread safe with the current standard.

---

> Is using singleton the best solution?

Probably not. Nothing should hinder you to revise your decisions later, and to decide you actually need to have more `ConnectionManager` instances.

Any other part of your code that will use `ConnectionManager::getManager();` is tightly coupled to that singleton class, and it will become hard to refactor your code if it should be made more generic.

This kind of hardcoding a DB connection

```
  ConnectionManager():m_connector("port")
                               // ^^^^^^
```

extremely narrows the scalability of your application.

---

I personally would make it a class, with the appropriate constructor parameters to create a connection, and having a public (abstract) interface implemented, that can be accessed via a factory function, or some of the other [Creational Design Patterns](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Programming/Code/Design_Patterns/Creational_Patterns) dedicated to instance creation, and nothing else.