# why cannot static function reference static variable during singleton class creation in c++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton

I was trying to understand singleton design pattern and created a simplest one:

```
#include <iostream>


class mySingleton{

private:
   static mySingleton *ptr;
   mySingleton(){ }    

public:
   static mySingleton* getInstance(){
     if(!ptr){
        ptr = new mySingleton();
        return ptr;
     } else return ptr;
   }

   void msg(){
     std::cout << " Hello World!! " << std::endl;
   }

};


int main(){

mySingleton* obj = mySingleton::getInstance();
mySingleton* obj2 = mySingleton::getInstance();

return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile I get :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"mySingleton::ptr", referenced from:
    mySingleton::getInstance()       in ccm822LI.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why can't I use ptr inside a static function, since ptr is also a static variable? Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Am I missing something here?

Yes, several things:

1. [As mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37998458/1413395) you are missing the definition of the static `mySingleton` pointer variable.
2. Your code isn't thread safe
   The correct way to implement it is to use a local static variable in the `getInstance()` function (aka. [Scott Meyer's Singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-singleton-pattern-thread-safe)):

   ```
   static mySingleton* getInstance(){
       static mySingleton theInstance;
       return &theinstance;
   }
   ```

   This implementation is guaranteed to be thread safe, and you don't need to bother with memory allocation.
3. Using a pointer probably isn't what you want as a return type

   ```
   static mySingleton& getInstance(){
                  // ^
       static mySingleton theInstance;
       return theinstance;
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for the answer .. one last thing I want to wrap my head around is .. so getInstance() can be called multiple times ... but how come the object it instantiate is always the same .. I know its because of static but I am still missing some thing that I need to understand

Comment: @pokche The 1st call to `getInstance()` triggers to create the instance, any following will get the same results as from the 1st call.

Comment: awesome .. I knew some thing like that has to happen ... but u explained clearly ... thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

```
static mySingleton *ptr;
```

inside the class definition is just a declaration. It is not a definition. You need to define it using:

```
mySingleton * mySingleton::ptr = nullptr;
```

outside the class definition.

Comment: @R Sahu So I cannot define the ptr inside the class static mySingleton *ptr = nullptr; .. cause when I do that I get compilation error.

Comment: @pokche But it doesn't even have to be a static *member*. It could be a static variable inside of the `getInstance` function.

Comment: @pokche And it doesn't even have to be a pointer to a dynamically allocated object either :-)