# Initialize static member inside constructor of an instance

Tags: c++, static-members, static-initialization

I want to initialize a static member variable inside the constructor of a particular instance. Is that a bad idea?

The situation is as follows. I have a static member variable that all instances of this class should share. Normally, I'd just use a static initializer. But, I don't have the necessary information needed to construct the static object until the constructor gets called. But of course, I don't want to create a new object every time the constructor gets called, so I want to do something like this.

```
class Foo
{
    static Bar * bar;
    Foo( Xyz xyz);
};

Bar * Foo::bar = nullptr;

Foo::Foo(Xyz xyz)
{
    if (Foo::bar == nullptr)
    {
         // initialize static bar 
         Foo::bar = new Bar(xyz);
    }
}
```

I know of course `xyz` migth be different for different calls to the constructor of `Foo`. That doesn't matter for me.

Is this bad software design? I feel a little weird initializing a static object inside the constructor. But it's not that different from the singleton design pattern. So maybe it is ok?

**EDIT**

Thanks for the comments guys. It seems like people are not a fan of this design. I will modify it so that I create a `Bar` once before the very first instantiation of `Foo`, and pass a `Bar *` as a parameter in `Foo`'s constructor. Each `Foo` will have a pointer to a `Bar`, and I'll make sure all `Foo`s are all pointing to the same `Bar`. Is that better?

Comment: Do note that you won't be doing initialization.  You will be doing assignment.

Comment: How do you obtain the value that should be used for _initialization_? Is it available at runtime only? BTW you sample won't compile.

Comment: Single threaded looks OK. Multi threaded race condition.

Comment: Why don't you use a static method and call it at the right time? Is it necessary to wait until the first instanciation?

Comment: _"But it's not that different from the singleton design pattern. So maybe it is ok?"_ Most experienced developers think that the _Singleton Pattern_ is not OK, or even an anti-pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this bad software design?

In general it would be considered so, yes. There are many reasons why the *Singleton Pattern* or having static variables in this way is considered bad design.

---

> But it's not that different from the singleton design pattern. So maybe it is ok?

If you really want to make that a *Singleton Pattern* you should rather use [Scott Meyer's technique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998408/why-cannot-static-function-reference-static-variable-during-singleton-class-crea/37998615#37998615):

```
class Foo
{
    static Bar* bar(Xyz xyz) {
        static Bar barInstance(xyz);
        return &barInstance;
    }
    Foo( Xyz xyz) : xyz_(xyz) {}

    void baz() {
        Bar* b = bar(xyz_);
        // use b ...
    }

private:
    Xyz xyz_;
};
```

This code will be thread safe, and avoids the need to check for a `nullptr`.

---

Though `Bar` should make up a *Singleton* on it's own then, and you use it in `Foo` whenever needed:

```
class Bar {
public:
    static Bar& getInstance(Xyz xyz) {
        static Bar barInstance(xyz);
        return &barInstance;
    }

private:
    Bar(Xyz xyz) : xyz_(Xyz) {}
    Bar(const Bar&) delete;
    Bar(Bar&&) delete;
    Bar& operator=(const Bar&) delete;
    Bar& operator=(Bar&) delete;

    Xyz xyz_;
};

class Foo {
public:
    Foo(Xyz xyz) barRef(Bar::getInstance(xyz)) {
                                      // ^^^ Notice 1st instance of Foo created
                                      //     wins to create the Bar actually
    }
private:
    Bar& barRef;
};
```

Comment: *"But, I don't have the necessary information needed to construct the static object until the constructor gets called"*...

Comment: @Jarod42 That's an indicator the design is flawed, and `Bar` shouldn't be in a static relation to `Foo`. I just try to clarify the difference from the _real_ Singleton Pattern.