# C++ singleton implementation with splitted declaration and definition of the singleton class

Tags: c++, c++11, singleton

Singleton implementation I have seen use the following code ([reference](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton)):

```cpp
// MySingleton.hpp
class MySingleton{
public:
  static MySingleton& getInstance(){
    static MySingleton instance;
    return instance;
  }

private:
  MySingleton()= default;
  ~MySingleton()= default;
  MySingleton(const MySingleton&)= delete;
  MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton&)= delete;
};
```

I would like to know if it is possible to split the declaration and the definition of `MySingleton` like this:

```cpp
// MySingleton.hpp
class MySingleton{
public:
  static MySingleton& getInstance();

private:
  MySingleton()= default;
  ~MySingleton()= default;
  MySingleton(const MySingleton&)= delete;
  MySingleton& operator=(const MySingleton&)= delete;
};
```

```cpp
// MySingleton.cpp
MySingleton& MySingleton::getInstance(){
  static MySingleton instance;
  return instance;
}
```

Other C++ singleton implementations I have seen use `static` pointer member variable, so I am wondering if having `static MySingleton instance;` in the `cpp` file is still correct?

Comment: did you try it? What did you compiler say about it?

Comment: Compilation is fine. I am more concerned about the validity of the implementation, especially with specific C++ details like `static` keyword (I am not a C++ expert).

Comment: I didn't find a good duplicate, but what you have is a Meyers singleton. Search for that term. Having the instance as static local in the method is rather common actually

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-the-singleton-pattern-thread-safe

Comment: External definition of class member functions in C++ source (with the declaration in header) is very usual. That the class forms a singleton doesn't change it. To have a `static` instance defined in the C++ source was usual in former times. (With newer C++ standard `static inline` became available which allows the definition of `static` things in the header but the older form is still valid.)