# Singleton still can copy the inner object even though I deleted all constructors

Tags: c++, singleton

I can see everybody recommending to add `delete` to all copy constructor / move / assignment operator, but doing all this I can still assign the instance.
Here is my singleton code :

```
class SingleTone
{
public:

    SingleTone(SingleTone& other) = delete;
    SingleTone& operator=(const SingleTone&) = delete;
    SingleTone& operator=(SingleTone&&) = delete;
    SingleTone* operator=(const SingleTone*) = delete;

     
    static SingleTone* instance()
    {
        if (singletone == nullptr)
        {
            singletone = new SingleTone();
        }
        return singletone;
    }
    int get1()
    {
        return 1;
    }
private:
    SingleTone() {};
    static SingleTone* singletone;
};

SingleTone* SingleTone::singletone = nullptr;
```

But in main, I can still do:

```
SingleTone *ss = SingleTone::instance();
```

Now I will have 2 instances.

Comment: instance return a pointer, you are deleting operation over the object, not its pointer. Check the pointer value it will be the same

Comment: See also [Is Meyers' implementation of the Singleton pattern thread safe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-the-singleton-pattern-thread-safe) which is less code and also thread-safe.

Comment: Change to `static SingleTone& instance()` to return by reference of the one instance.

Comment: You are copying a pointer, and no amount of deleting of constructors will stop that happening, since no objects are constructed when you copy a pointer. Clearly you have two pointers pointing at the same single instance.

Comment: *"`SingleTone* operator=(const SingleTone*)`"* -- this is not one of the standard assignment operators, so there is no need to introduce it only to declare (via `=delete`) that it does not exist. (Also, this operator would not handle the case that I suspect you think it does.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will have multiple pointers to the same instance. As @Richard Critten mentioned Meyers' implementation of the Singleton along with other benefits will not allow multiple pointers.

```
    static SingleTone& instance()
    {
        static SingleTone singletone; //remove singletone private member
        return singletone;
    }
```

Comment: why it is valid ? i mean the static singletone

Comment: @user63898 Why not? What problem to you see? It's perfectly normal C++.