# Allowing only one object and disabling all assignments (including copies of static pointer)

Tags: c++, singleton

I am familiar with a singleton class concept, where we use a static pointer to point to one and only one instance of a class.

https://qnaplus.com/singleton-class-in-c/

I am also familiar with disabling the assignment operator and copy constructor, by having both the methods under private.

I am trying to take it further. It is possible to prevent creating multiple copies of the pointer that points to the same object?

```
  Singleton *p = Singleton::Instance();
  Singleton *q = Singleton::Instance();   // Can I make this fail?

  auto A = p;                             // Can I make this fail?
```

Just thinking wildly here if there is no way to restrict the above statements. Assuming we use the default constructor method of creating objects, can I delete the default constructor after creating the first object? The below code is an example that obviously doesn't work.

```
class Singleton {
public:
  Singleton() {
    Singleton() = delete;
  } // default constructor
```

Comment: If you were asked: how would you write a function so that the 2nd time it gets called it throws an exception, how would you write that? It seems a fairly simple, straightforward, programming task, right? So, what do you believe is different between that, and the singleton factory function?

Comment: "disabling the assignment operator and copy constructor, by having both the methods under private." - Better/more explicit would be to mark them as deleted - `= delete;` since C++11.

Comment: Btw; IMHO singletons should be avoided. They are nothing more than glorified global variables, with all the same problems.

Comment: No, this is not possible. And the singleton flavor suggested by your link isn't threadsafe and uses an unnecessary heap allocation, prefer [Meyer's singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1661529/2752075).

Comment: Instead of returning a raw pointer to the instance, rather return a proxy object to the instance, and make that proxy object not copy-able or assign-able.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I think I just figured it out. Static variable flag under private, and toggle flag when the default constructor is called.  Next time the constructor is called, I can assert.

Comment: What do you perceive as the *benefit* of disallowing multiple pointers to the same instance? I can't see any.

Comment: @user207421, to be honest, I was just thinking of how tight I can make these checks. Not much experience on what potential problems could arise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am familiar with a singleton class concept

Ok, so these answers to your questions will not dwell further into the depth of singletons.

> It is possible to prevent creating multiple copies of the pointer that points to the same object?

No, that's not within your control - unless you control the whole chain where the pointer is revealed.

> Assuming we use the default constructor method of creating objects, can I delete the default constructor after creating the first object?

No, that's not at all possible.