# Implementation of C++ Singleton Class

Tags: c++, static, singleton

I need help with understanding if my implementation of a static singleton class is efficient or considered best practice.

I am currently working on a hobbyist OpenGL engine, and I have multiple singleton classes for systems such as logging, profiling, etc., and I use these statically throughout the engine and my applications that depend on the engine.

I have seen this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/8509611) that talks about the implementation of a singleton class.

The below is how I originally approached this:

-- Log.h --

```
#pragma once
#include <assert.h>

class Log {

public:

    static Log& Init() {
        if (!s_Instance) // EDIT 1: Forgot to add this to the post.
            s_Instance = new Log();

        return *s_Instance;
    }

    static Log& Get() {

        assert(s_Instance, "Logger not initialised!");

        return *s_Instance;
    }

    // Delete copy assignment and move assignment constructors
    Log(const Log&) = delete;
    Log(Log&&) = delete;

    // Delete copy assignment and move assignment operators
    Log& operator=(const Log&) = delete;
    Log& operator=(Log&&) = delete;

private:

    Log() {
    }

    static Log* s_Instance;
};
```

-- Log.cpp --

```
#include "Log.h"

Log* Log::s_Instance = nullptr;
```

As you can see from my code I want to be able to determine when in the program this class is initialised using a static Init function. Would I be better off going with the suggested approach through the answer linked above, or is this considered just as good for my purposes?

Comment: [Use a Meyers singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1661529/is-meyers-implementation-of-the-singleton-pattern-thread-safe).  What is stopping two or more functions from calling your `Log::Init()`?

Comment: Don't use singletons. It's an anti-pattern and now recognized as bad.

Comment: As mentioned, try to avoid singletons.  But even with your latest edit, your singleton is not thread-safe.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Updated the pseudo code now. I want to be able to determine exactly when the init function is called, so that any other dependencies can be initialised in correct order.

Comment: @Jeffrey what do you suggest I do some research into?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Note that the use of a singleton is almost always a bad design choice. But if you do it don't create instances with `new` but use `Log& Instance() { static Log log; return log; }` at least the instantiation will be threadsafe (since C++11) and the instance will be properly destructed. To avoid the singleton all together give it an abstract baseclass and learn about dependency injection.

Comment: Don't use Meyers singleton, it's that nasty variant that everyone complains about because it offers no control over object lifetime. The problem with code in the question is that it is missing a method to delete created object and condition `if (!s_Instance)` should be an `assert` to catch an accidental double init attempt. Or (better) remove object constructor from singleton and make it accept an object instance passed from caller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your engine works in a single-threaded mode, it is good for now. I highly recommend that you consider the aforementioned answer linked above (Meyers Singleton), it is safe in a multi-threaded environment.

I would like to recommend this article to you for reference, which discusses various ways of implementing singletons, their functionalities, and performance differences.

[singletons in cpp](https://www.modernescpp.com/index.php/thread-safe-initialization-of-a-singleton/)

Comment: cheers for the response! I'm just going to go with the Meyers singleton pattern. At the end of the day it's currently just a hobbyist project that I'm doing!

Answer (score -2):

For everyone considering using global singletons, do not do that.
It will be bad for unit testing!

This is an example of how to completely avoid needing a global singleton variable for logging using dependency injection instead.
And yes it might seem "a lot of work" now, but for larger systems this (dependency injection) is an important design pattern.

Demo here : https://onlinegdb.com/5-KzFk5c1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>

// assume you have a bit of code that needs to log something
// In this example I made a temperature sensor that needs to do some logging
// but the temperature sensor doesn't want to know anything about the logging system
// In that case make an interface that allows your temperature sensor to report something.

class temparature_sensor_report_itf
{
public:
    virtual ~temparature_sensor_report_itf() = default;
    virtual void report_temparature(int temp) = 0;
    virtual void report_too_hot() = 0;
};

// Now you can write your code to use this interface
class logger_t
{
public:
    // The initialization of the logger is to be done
    // using a constructor
    explicit logger_t(std::string_view filename)
        : m_filename{filename}
    {
    }

    void log(std::string_view msg)
    {
        std::cout << "Logging: " << msg << "\n";
    }

private:
    std::string m_filename;
};

// now make an adapter from report_itf to a specific logger_t
// this allows you to change the logger_t without changing the
// code that uses the temparature_sensor_report_itf (the temperature sensor class)
class temparature_sensor_logger_t : 
    public temparature_sensor_report_itf
{
public:
    temparature_sensor_logger_t(logger_t& logger)
        : m_logger{logger}
    {
    }

    void report_temparature(int temp) override
    {
        m_logger.log("Temperature: " + std::to_string(temp));
    }

    void report_too_hot() override
    {
        m_logger.log("Too hot!");
    }

private:
    logger_t& m_logger;
};

// For unit testing you can now also make a reporter class that does nothing at all
class temperature_sensor_report_nothing_t : 
    public temparature_sensor_report_itf
{
public:
    void report_temparature(int temp) override
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    void report_too_hot() override
    {
        // do nothing
    }
};

// The temperature sensor class doesn't know anything about the logger
// it only has an injected dependency to the temparature_sensor_report_itf

class temparature_sensor_t
{   
public:
    explicit temparature_sensor_t(temparature_sensor_report_itf& reporter)
        : m_sensor_reporter{reporter}
    {
    }

    void read_temparature()
    {
        // read the temperature
        int temp = 42;

        // report the temperature
        // but you don't know anything about the logger here.
        m_sensor_reporter.report_temparature(temp);

        if (temp > 40)
        {
            m_sensor_reporter.report_too_hot();
        }
    }

private:
    temparature_sensor_report_itf& m_sensor_reporter;
};
   

int main()
{
    // do NOT make a global logger initialize your logging system in main
    // this also allows the destructor of your logger to do nice things
    // like flushing the log file and closing it (something you cannot do
    // when you use a singleton with a new but no delete)
    logger_t logger{"log.txt"};

    // now create a small adapter, this adapter allows you to change
    // the logging infrastructure later without ever needing
    // to change anything in the temparature_sensor_t class
    temparature_sensor_logger_t reporter{logger};

    // In unit tests you use this line instead of the previous one
    // And now you can test without for example depending on the filestystem 
    // temperature_sensor_report_nothing_t reporter;

    // now create the temparature sensor
    // by injecting a class derived from temparature_sensor_report_itf
    // For unit testing we will inject the temperature_sensor_report_nothing_t instance
    temparature_sensor_t sensor{reporter};

    // now read the temperature, if something needs to be reported
    // it will be reported to the logger
    sensor.read_temparature();

    return 0;
}
```