# How can I avoid static data member init fiasco in a thread-safe way?

Tags: c++, concurrency, thread-safety

Consider this:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const char* s) { /*...*/ };
    static const A& get_default() { /* avoid static data memember init fiasco */
        static const A& a = A("default"); /* ..but not thread-safe */
        return a;
    }
};
```

How can I make `get_default()` thread safe? Or how can I find a way to get the `A::a` avoiding both the data member init fiasco and concurrency. I prefer not to use any locks.

Comment: FWIW, this is already perfectly threadsafe in C++0x.

Comment: In c++0x maybe (could you post a link). But c++0x is not standard yet.

Comment: This is not the static initialization order fiasco. [This is](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14).

Comment: @Space: Indeed.  But the OP's code snippet is one way to avoid it.  Except it has issues in a multi-threaded context.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449436/singleton-instance-declared-as-static-variable-of-getinstance-method/449823#449823

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will take advantage of the fact that initialization before `main()` is called will take place on a single thread, and that the `pInstance` pointer must be zero initialized before dynamic initialization of static objects takes place (3.6.2 "Initialization of non-local objects").

```
class A {
public:
    A(const char* s) { /*...*/ };

    static const A& get_default() { 
        if (!pInstance) {
            static const A default_instance("default");
            pInstance = &default_instance;
        }
        return *pInstance;
    }

private:
    static A const* pInstance;
};

A const* A::pInstance = &A::get_default();
```

So, `pInstance` will be NULL the first time that `get_default()` is called - whether or not that call is due to the initialization of `A::pInstance`.  That will cause `get_default()` to initialize it (`pInstance` will get 'needlessly' overwritten with the same value whenever it's initializer runs - but that'll be on the single init thread, so there are no threading issues).  And just to be clear, the initializer for `pInstance` will force `get_default()` to be called on the init thread even if nothing else does.

Subsequent calls to `get_default()` will not modify `pInstance`, so it's threadsafe.

Note that the simpler:

```
class A {
public:
    A(const char* s) { /*...*/ };

    static const A& get_default() { 
        static const A& a = A("default"); /* ..but not thread-safe */
        return a;
    }
};

namespace {
    A const& trigger = A::get_default();
}
```

Should also be threadsafe for the same reason, but it has a couple areas that make me a little less certain that it won't have some potential drawbacks:

- if the toolchain determines that `trigger` isn't used elsewhere (and this applies even if we take it out of the anonymous namespace), I'd worry that it might get removed from the program image. I'm not sure about what promises the standard might make about preventing this optimization - particularly if `class A` lives in a library.
- presumably the compiler simply checks a hidden static flag to determine if the initialization of the local `static` variable in `get_default()` has been run before.  However, there's really no promise about what mechanism is used (I haven't looked into what C++0x might say about this).  With the first example, the threadsafe check after the init time `get_default()` call is right there - guaranteed.

Comment: Thank you Michael. This the solution I have been searching for!