# Why the singleton works here, although a static variable is re-initialized to NULL?

Tags: c++

In this example, I expected that the instance was re-initialzed to NULL everytime. Thus, it shouldn't have worked, it should do new everytime. But, it works actually as singleton. Thus,the new is called only once. Why it works? I am confused here.

```
class Factory_model
{
public:

    static  Factory_model*    Instance(void);

};

Factory_model*    Factory_model::Instance(void)
{
    static Factory_model* instance = NULL;

    if(instance == NULL)
    {
        qDebug()<< "Creating instance now"<<endl;
        instance = new Factory_model;

    }

    return(instance);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

   Factory_model *ptr =  Factory_model::Instance();
   Factory_model *ptr2 =  Factory_model::Instance();
   Factory_model *ptr3 = Factory_model::Instance();
}
```

The output is the following - 
Creating instance now

Comment: Note the difference between `static Factory_model* instance = NULL;` and `static Factory_model* instance; instance = NULL;`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I expected that the instance was re-initialzed to NULL everytime.

No, static variables are only initialised once, the first time the program reaches the definition (or earlier if, as here, it can be statically initialised).

<sub>Of course, you've got a memory leak, and the object creation isn't thread-safe; but this isn't the place for [yet another essay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975) about the perils of the Singleton anti-pattern.</sub>

Comment: What memory leak I have injected here? Also, why isn't it thread safe.

Comment: @SHREYASJOSHI: There's a `new` with no matching `delete`, therefore a memory leak. If two threads both call the function simultaneously, they might both find the variable to be null, and both create the object. (It's probably not worth trying to fix the leak, as the alternatives will quickly lead to a nightmare of lifetime issues. You can bodge around the threading problem, if necessary, by deliberately calling the accessor before starting threads. Or you can save yourself a lot of pain by giving up on the idea of a Singleton.)

Comment: Another definition of a leak is an object with no reference to it; under this definition it is not a leak.

Comment: @Bryan: OK; I was using the definition of an object that was created and not destroyed. But lets not get bogged down in semantic quibbling about a remark that's not particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: True, also thread safe part is dependent on how I am going to access the common code, a mutex can prevent such conditions.  So, it should be consider will making the thread and not here.

Answer (score 2):

The line:

```
static Factory_model* instance = NULL;
```

is only executed once; that is what the keyword `static` means when you use it on a local variable.  The initialisation is not executed every time you enter the function.

See [The static keyword and its various uses in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15235526/the-static-keyword-and-its-various-uses-in-c) or http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/statickeyword.html

Answer (score 1):

also, have a look at this:

[Singleton instance declared as static variable of GetInstance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449436/singleton-instance-declared-as-static-variable-of-getinstance-method)

...every time c++ static variables and singleton are involved, this is a technique you should know

Answer (score 0):

```
static Factory_model* instance = NULL;
```

creates a static storage duration variable called `instance` and initialises it *once.* You are correct in that a variant *without* the `static` keyword would be initialised each time, but the `static` makes a difference here.

It's effectively the same as if you had declared it *outside* the function, but with the added bonus of minimising scope (what can *see* the variable). Creating a static storage duration variable inside the function means that only the function can see/use it (absent any trickiness in publishing a pointer or reference to it), and it maintains its value across function invocations.