# singleton in c++ compile error

Tags: c++, singleton

I tried to make the following singleton class in C++

```
#pragma once
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

class God
{
private:
    static God* firstObject;
    God()
    {
        if (firstObject != NULL)
            firstObject = this;
    }
public:
    static God* BuildGod()
    {
        if (firstObject != NULL)
            return firstObject;
        else {
            God();
            return firstObject;
        }
    }
};
```

and then use it like so

```
God* a = God::BuildGod();
```

Unfortunatley, it won't even compile and it returned the following errors:

> LNK2001 unresolved external symbol "private: static class God * God::firstObject" (?firstObject@God@@0PAV1@A)
>
> LNK1120   1 unresolved externals

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/449436/singleton-instance-declared-as-static-variable-of-getinstance-method if you are interested in making it thread safe in C++11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually have a *worse* problem than the build error, because you create a *temporary* object, and save a pointer to it to be used.

The statement

```
God();
```

creates a *temporary* object, and in the constructor you save a pointer to this temporary object in `firstObject` which you then return. Using that pointer will then lead to *undefined behavior*.

*One* of the usual ways of creating a singleton in C++ would be something like this:

```
class God
{
public:
    static God& get_instance() {
    {
        static God instance;  // This is THE instance
        return instance;
    }

private:
    God() {}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A static member of a class has to be defined outside the class, like

```
class God
{
...
};

God* God::firstObj;
```

Just beware that having the definition in a header file and including it mamy times calls for trouble.

Comment: holy shit man, that worked fine!
thanks
EDIT:
just tried to add cast operator just in case as shown:
`operator const char*()
 {
  return "sup";
 }`
it gives me the same error again

Comment: Don't get what your code looks like now, this works https://ideone.com/nOIINQ