# Why might a factory member function hang in the constructor for a global object?

Tags: c++, initialization, factory, freeze

To preface, I do not have a complete minimum functional example here to define the factory because I don't have access to the definitions of the dynamic library I'm using.

What I'm looking for right now is suggestions for reading, unless my issue is clearly a general one and doesn't require knowledge of the function definitions to explain.

Suppose we have some variation of a factory pattern which allows the following to compile and operate as intended, per the documentation that came with the DLL:

```cpp
int main(){
   std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;

   Base* ptr = Base::Create();
   ptr->ConcreteMemberDoSomething();

   std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

With output:

```
Start
/-- Concrete Member... Output --/
End
```

With that in mind, why might this compile but (consistently) cause the program to hang indefinitely when run?:

```cpp
class Init{
public:
   Base* ptr;
   Init(){
      std::cout << "Ctor start" << std::endl;

      ptr = Base::Create();

      std::cout << "Ctor end" << std::endl;
   };
   ~Init(){
      std::cout << "Dtor" << std::endl;
   };
}

Init obj;

int main(){
   std::cout << "Start" << std::endl;

   obj.ptr->ConcreteMemberDoSomething();

   std::cout << "End" << std::endl;
}
```

With output:

```
Ctor start
```

I expect that I have more debugging to do with my `main()`, but I don't understand why the `Init` constructor freezes. I'm worried it's something to do with the initialization order, since I've been reading about the static initialization order problem, but I don't know what I could try to fix it since I don't have access to any of the definitions compiled in the dynamic library.

Comment: they both do the same thing effectively. From what you have shown it is not possible to know why one works while the other doesnt

Comment: get the debug version of the library and attach a debugger then you will know where it hangs

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number That's why I'm confused. What information would I need/need to provide to narrow down the set of possible problems?

Comment: it is `Base::Create()` that doesnt return so the issue seems to be there.

Comment: I bet you have a bug in the code not provided.  But it's hard to tell without a [mcve], and I wasn't able to divine the suspected bug.

Comment: btw I doubt that it is actually `Base::Create()`. I suppose in reality its a factory that takes some parameters, and i hope it returns not a raw pointer. That might already help. Its information you should have available

Comment: @Eljay I've only recently started learning about factory patterns. It's immediately obvious that the DLL developers used a factory pattern, but their implementation is very confusing to me since they appear to have mixed-and-matched portions from different "standard" patterns. It's not clear to me from the headers alone how they compiled it without major dependency issues.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number They give examples that are essentially `myClass* ptr = myClass::Create(&parameters)`. I would expect that `myClass` is the client class, but `myClass` has pure virtual members and both dependent classes that I've found headers for are set up as subclasses of `myClass`. Would you say the issue I've described would probably become apparent if I focused on understanding how they've set up their factory, if that's possible without the class definitions?

Comment: from what I see and read, I would suggest you focus on understanding polymorphism first. Only then you can understand how a factory works and what it is good for

Comment: Testing for static initialization order fiasco is not hard: put the definition of `obj` inside `main` instead of global, to check if that is the case. If positive, then come back for the solution.

Comment: @Red.Wave That did indeed compile, with the desired output order: `Ctor start`, `Ctor end`, `Start`, `/-- Concrete Member... Output --/`, `End`,`Dtor`.

Comment: 1. Do you need a global/static object? If not, then don't make it global/static. 2. Is there a `Base::Destroy` method? Or you have to `delete` the returned object? Or you are supposed to totally leave the destruction to the dynamic library? What is the memory management schema?

Comment: @Red.Wave Unfortunately, I do need a global/static object. I need the scope of the concrete object to be as broad as I can get it. There is not a `Base::Destroy` method, no. I suspect that `Base::create` `new`'s a derived class object, and `~Base` directs through to the `delete`. Memory management is entirely up to the dynamic library here.

Comment: To be clear I already extensively explored creating a global object, or an explicit memory allocation, and copying the data from the `Base::create` to that. However, there is nontrivial data involved somewhere (byte copies don't work) and since the factory interface is an abstract class, I only have a pointer to work with.

Comment: Now my typos are gone. See if the answer is fit.

Comment: There will be something specific to your situation that has caused the problem you are seeing - and you haven't provided relevant information, so nobody can help you.   There are many possibilities for why a program might hang during construction of an object (code with undefined behaviour [notionally, an infinite number of ways behaviour may be undefined], compiler bugs, operating system refusing to allocate a resource and your program waits indefinitely for it to be allocated, etc etc) so asking for a set of possible reasons rather than offering specifics on your situation is pointless.

Comment: @Peter There are probably subtleties I need to consider before finalizing my implementation, but I believe Red.Wave's answer has solved my immediate problem. For my reading, I expect I'll need to go learn about singletons now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a probable case of [*static initialization order fiasco*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). Although other sorts of problems are probable, this speculation is based solely on the provided snippet code. Generally speaking, creating none-function-local static objects with dynamic initialization is considered bad programming practice and if it is indeed inevitable (e.g `std::cout`), [carefully designed ad-hoc workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844393/c-nifty-counter-idiom-why) must be considered.

One way to get around this problem is known as [*Scott Mayer's Singleton*](https://laristra.github.io/flecsi/src/developer-guide/patterns/meyers_singleton.html). User code must not store any pointers or references to the singleton object and always use `singleton_t::instance()`. Some recommend wrapping the Mayer's singleton in a monostate type:

```
struct mono{
    single* const operator ->() const{
        static single ret{/*TODO:init stuff here*/};
        return std::addressof(ret);
    };
};
//...
{
    //In Some code scope:
    mono x;
    use(x->y);
};
```

In the context of OP, assuming the existence of a `destroy` counterpart for `create` we can use a `unique_ptr`:

```
struct mono{
    auto const operator ->() const{
        static std::unique_ptr
                    <Base,
                    decltype([](Base *const ptr)
                            {Base::Destroy(ptr);})>
               ret {Base::Create();};
        return ret;
    };
};
```

If the such `Destroy` exists and the object is not supposed to be `delete`d at all, then instead of a smart pointer, a raw pointer can be used.

Comment: While I now have other issues to deal with, I believe your answer has solved the immediate problem I had asked about. Much appreciated! Edit: to be clear, my other issues were expected and (I believe) are unrelated to the issue I had asked about.

Comment: Start new threads then