# Releasing attributes' memory of singleton class

Tags: c++, singleton

Considering the following Singleton class, I am not releasing memory in the destructor. But the instance of this class will remain the life-time of the program as most of the single-ton class do. Is it really matter to release the attribute's memory other than best practices perception?

```
class Singleton
{
private:
    Singleton() { pbyte1 = new BYTE[100]; }
    ~Singleton() {};
    BYTE* pbyte1;
    static SingletonInstance* pInstance;

    public:

    static Singleton* GetInstance()
    {
        if( pInstace ) return pInstance; 
        else 
        pInstance = new Singleton();
    }
};
```

Comment: Why the emphasis on the "T" - it's a singleton - one word.. :)

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993400/managing-a-singleton-destructor/6993501#6993501

Comment: @Nim: The word "singleton" is a singleton word!

Comment: Sounds like quite a heavy class. I prefer the single-cwt class personally - it's a bit lighter.

Comment: @sarat: What do you mean by "best practices"? If it's the *best* practice, do it. There's nothing better than it, by definition.

Comment: The best practice is not to use singletons at all. It is just a hidden global variable anyway

Comment: Thanks @nim. I updated. 
Anyway this isn't a real-world class. I was just giving out a sample.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does matter for debugging. If you run a tool for detecting memory leaks, the leaks caused by this singleton will pollute the output, making it harder to detect real memory leaks.

Comment: Excellent! you got it right. It's the same story here. Because some people have already did it in this way and the tool gives hell lot of warnings :) You mean to say, I should release the resources?

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the nature of the resources.  Usually, the best practice
is **not** to destruct the singleton; destructing the singleton can give
rise to order of destructor problems.  The exception is if the singleton
uses resources which won't be freed by the system (e.g. temporary
files); in this case, the "classical" implementation of the `instance()`
function is:

```
Singleton& Singleton::instance()
{
    static Singleton theOneAndOnly;
    return theOneAndOnly;
}
```

In this case, the destructor of `theOneAndOnly` will be called during
shutdown.  For this reason, you must ensure that the singleton is never
used in the destructor of a static variable.

By the way, you're implementation is broken as well.  It should be:

```
Singleton& Singleton::instance()
{
    static Singleton* theOneAndOnly = new Singleton;
    return *theOneAndOnly;
}
```

This is the usual solution.

Comment: Can't say it's broken. Some people prefer to use pointers rather than references.

Comment: @sarat: you're not returning pInstance in your else clause

Comment: @sarat It's not a question of pointers or references (although returning a pointer means that the caller has to check for a possible null pointer).  The code in the function is broken.

Answer (score 2):

As Björn said: it matters for debugging.

It matters also for maintenance. The program will change. It will be refactored. If during refactoring a singleton suddenly isn't a singleton anymore, the missing destructor might introduce real leaks. Additionally, in the future the object might need more than memory (e.g. db handles). Not returning them on closing the program is a true error.

So if you want a best practice: **Every destructor should return the resources the object owns.** This includes destructors of objects where you could rely on the OS to take them on program shutdown.

Answer (score 0):

If the singleton instance is remaining for the lifetime, then no need to worry about releasing the `class` resources. When the program terminates, they will vanish (I don't mean automatic `delete`).

The best practice is to declare the class objects as automatic when the size is fixed.

```
class SingleTon
{
//...
  BYTE pbyte1[100];
//...
};
```

Comment: "then no need to worry about releasing the class resources" <- Really? There are resources other than memory. Yes, they will all "vanish", but sometimes you want them released, not "vanished".

Comment: @R. Martinho, I know that ideally we should release all the resources. But in this case how/when should we release the member resources of the `class SingleTon`; OP is expecting to retain the pointer `SingleTon*` for the lifetime of the program.

Comment: Yes, that is one of the many problems a singleton introduces. Why the OP wanted to introduce this problem is beyond my knowledge, though.