# Singletons destructors

Tags: c++, boost, singleton, destructor

I'm using boost's singletons (boost::serialization::singleton).
I have to control the queue of class destructings. One singleton consist of the object whicn uses object from second singleton. And I have to delete second singleton, before the first one. Can I do this?

p.s. please, don't say anything about singleton programming technique :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Finding C++ static initialization order problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335369/finding-c-static-initialization-order-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes:

Read this: [Finding C++ static initialization order problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335369/finding-c-static-initialization-order-problems/335746#335746)

Answer (score 0):

If you can reference the second singleton from the first using `boost::weak_ptr` you may be able to do what you wish to here.  The first would need to make sure the `weak_ptr` is still live before using the second singleton.