# Guaranteeing correct initialization order of global variables

Tags: c++

I have implemented custom class representing an enumeration possibilities similarily to [this article](http://www.drdobbs.com/when-enum-just-isnt-enough-enumeration-c/184403955?pgno=1):

```
// Color.h

class Color {
public:
    static const Color Red;
    static const Color Green;
    static const Color Blue;
    //...
private:
    explicit Color(int code);
    //...

    int code;
    static std::set<Color> colors;
};

// Color.cpp:

const Color Color::Red(1);
const Color Color::Green(2);
const Color Color::Blue(3);    
//...
```

Now I have problem when I want to use instances of `Color` e.g.: `Color::Red` to initialize a global variable in another translation unit. I understand that it happens because it is not defined which translation unit global variables are initialized first. How the initialization ordering problem could be solved?

The only solution that I can think of is using nifty counter. But I am not able find out, how to use it without affecting syntax of the enumeration class. I was thinking about adding `set()` method into `Color`. Then I could call this method in a nifty counter like initializer:

```
// Color.h

class Color {
public:
    void set(int code);
    //...
private:
    Color() { /* empty */}
    //...
};

static class ColorInitializer {
    ColorInitializer () {
        static bool initialized = false;
        if(initialized)
            return;

        Color::Red.set(1);
        Color::Green.set(1);
        Color::Blue.set(1);
        initialized = true;
    }
} colorInitializer;

// Color.cpp

const Color Color::Red;
const Color Color::Green;
const Color Color::Blue;
```

But the problem I see here is that the `set` method could be called on object that is not yet constructed. Is that OK or is the behavior undefined? How to better solve the problem of undefined initialization order?

Comment: I do not have experience with C++11, but I seriously suspect that the whole approach with `ColorInitializer` is not good. Better investigate using initialization with `{...}`, etc. What error are you getting for your fist code sample?

Comment: @Kirill Kobelev: I am not getting any compilation errors, it is only an undefined behavior. The variable may or may not be initialized when it is used.

Comment: Then I would suspect that this behavior has no relation to your particular class. Try to isolate the problem. Something is wrong with linker?

Comment: The simplest way to guarantee the correct initialisation order is not to have any globals.

Comment: @Frerich Raabe: As you can see, my accept ratio is pretty high. That means I know how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++11 (if you can afford using it) you could use extended constant expression functionality:

```
class Color {
public:
    static constexpr const Color Red;
    static constexpr const Color Green;
    static constexpr const Color Blue;
private:
    constexpr explicit Color(int code);
    //...
};

// Color.cpp:

constexpr Color Color::Red(1);
constexpr Color Color::Green(2);
constexpr Color Color::Blue(3);    
//...
```

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately, this is used in an old project and C++11 is not an option at least for now.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use global objects in the first place. Instead, use functions:

```
class Color {
public:
    static const Color &Red() {
      static const Color c( 1 );
      return c;
    }

    static const Color &Green() {
      static const Color c( 2 );
      return c;
    }

    static const Color &Blue() {
      static const Color c( 3 );
      return c;
    }
private:
    explicit Color(int code);
    //...
};
```

You can now use these functions to initialize other objects; calling them will ensure that the constructor of the `Color` objects is called.

Comment: Unfortunately, **this is not thread-safe on C++03** (although it is on C++11 and recent versions of gcc). See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/335369/finding-c-static-initialization-order-problems/335746#335746

Answer (score 2):

Since your Colour objects are lightweight, just could just use static functions.

```
class Color {
public:
    static Color Red() { return Color(1); }
    static Color Green() { return Color(2); }
    static Color Blue() { return Color( 3 ); }
private:
    explicit Color(int code);
};
```

The only problem with this is you can not pass these objects, to functions expecting pointers or non-const references (but non-const references in this case is probably nonsensical anyway).