# global static variable vs static variable in function?

Tags: c++

What's the diference between use:

```
static Foo foo;
// ...
foo.func();
```

And:

```
Foo& GetFoo(void) 
{
    static Foo foo;
    return foo;
}

// ...

GetFoo().func();
```

Which is better?

Comment: With the global variable you risk naming conflicts.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12186857/on-local-and-global-static-variables-in-c.

Comment: @VoidStar: With the global function you risk naming conflicts.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The principal difference is when construction occurs. In the first case, it occurs sometime before `main()` begins. In the second case, it occurs during the first call to `GetFoo()`.

It is possible, in the first case, for code to (illegally) use `foo` prior to its initialization. That is not possible in the second case.

Comment: While the intent is correct, with enough effort you can use the function static (in C++03) before initialization through recursive calls to the function.

Answer (score 1):

A `GetFoo` is generally used when you don't want copies of your class/object.
For example:

```
class Foo
{
private:
    Foo(){};
    ~Foo();
public:
    static Foo* GetFoo(void) 
    {
        static Foo foo;
        return &foo;
    }

    int singleobject;
};
```

You can externally access `singleobject` via `Foo::GetFoo()->sinlgeobject`. The private constructors and destructors avoid your class getting copies created.

For the use of `static Foo foo`, you must have public constructors declared which means you are always accessing your class by it, but your class will also be able to get copies.