# How to share variable across files in different directory

Tags: c++, extern

I have a variable defines in one .cpp file.

(file1.cpp)

```
int N;
....
N =3;
```

(directory/file2.cpp)  ---->  file2.cpp is in another directory.

```
extern int N;

cout << n << endl ;    -----> It is printing 0.
```

It should hv printed 3..right ? What is the mistake I am doing..Please let me know. Directory Structure is:

(main Directory)

```
file1.cpp   directory
```

(directory)

```
file2.cpp
```

Thanks,
Avinash

Comment: Possible duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12290451/access-extern-variable-in-c-from-another-file

Comment: `n` is a different variable to `N`. C++ is csae sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

In one file this variable should be define as is:

```
  int N;
```

in others as `extern` (it is better to use header file to include such declaration), i.e.:

```
  extern int N;
```

The directory structure is not important, just cpp files must be compiled together to allow linker resolving connections.

Answer (score 0):

To make it work you can use following approach:

Header file which provides the declarations so that other translation units can easily import it:

```
// dir1/file1.hpp
extern int N;
```

Implementation file with variable definition:

```
// dir1/file1.cpp
int N = 3;
```

Example client which uses the variable:

```
// main.cpp
#include "dir1/file1.hpp"

#include <iostream>

int main () {
    std::cout << N << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Note that include guards are omitted in dir1/file1.hpp