# Accessing a global variable defined in a .cpp file in another .cpp file

Tags: c++, extern

Consider the following scenario:

*MyFile.cpp*:

`const int myVar = 0;` // global variable

*AnotherFile.cpp*:

```
void myFun()
{
    std::cout << myVar; // compiler error: Undefined symbol
}
```

Now if I add `extern const int myVar;` in *AnotherFile.cpp* before using, linker complains as

> Unresolved external

I can move the declaration of `myVar` to *MyFile.h* and include *MyFile.h* in *AnotherFile.cpp* to solve the issue. But I do not want to move the declaration to the header file. Is there any other way I can make this work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++, `const` [implies internal linkage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/998425/why-does-const-imply-internal-linkage-in-c-when-it-doesnt-in-c). You need to declare `myVar` as `extern` in MyFile.cpp:

```
extern const int myVar = 0;
```

The in AnotherFile.cpp:

```
extern const int myVar;
```

Comment: No, just keep compiling and linking as before.

Comment: Could you please post the command you use?

Comment: Oh sorry I thought you already declared it in AnotherFile.cpp. You need to put this in AnotherFile.cpp: `extern const int myVar;`