# Initializing const objcts in a namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, constants, static-initialization, destruction

I'm running into a problem with initializing some const objects in my namespace. I have a namespace like the following:

```
namespace myNamespace{
    const std::string HI = "Hi";
    const std::string BYE = "Bye";

    inline std::vector<std::string> createHiAndByeVector(){
        std::vector<std::string> temp;
        temp.push_back(HI);
        temp.push_back(BYE);
        return temp;
    }

    const std::vector<std::string> HI_AND_BYE = createHiAndByeVector();
}
```

If I debug the initialization, I can see that both `HI` and `BYE` get assigned the string literals. The execution continues on to initialziae `HI_AND_BYE`, but when we get into the `createHiAndByeVector()` function, both `HI` and `BYE` have no values anymore. I then get a segmentation fault in the `push_back()` method. If I look at the call stack, I see the line: `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0()`. What is going on? Are my objects getting destroyed immediately after they're constructed?

Comment: Why so cumbersome: You can just say `std::vector<std::string> const HI_AND_BYE { "Hi", "Bye" };`.

Comment: All these definitions appear in the same translation unit (.cpp file)?

Comment: You have another static member depends on `HI_AND_BYE`? kind of static initialize order issue

Comment: @KerrekSB I didn't know that was possible! Thanks, that seems to work.

However, is there one and only one `vector` created no matter how many translation units this header file is included in?

Comment: @Wagan8r: Well, you have to put the definition into the source file and only the declaration into the header...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the problem here is a violation of the One Definition Rule (ODR). The guessing here is that this code is actually in a header, which is also the reason you declared the function as inline.

Now, this code is compiled in multiple translation units (.cpp files), TU1 and TU2. This leads to two sets of both the constants and the inline function. Now, when linking, the constants exist independently of each other because they have internal linkage (const at namespace level causes this). However, the function does not have internal linkage, rather the linker is instructed to discard all instances but one via the `inline`. Now, the remaining one is used to initialize the vectors in both TU1 and TU2, but it uses the constant strings from one of them. Depending on when these are initialized, which is undefined, it can work or not. This is basically the initialization order fiasco that Deamonpog above mentions.

Getting back to the ODR, the problem is that the inline function is compiled twice but they are not the same, because they implicitly refer to different string constants. Similar problems arise when you have anonymous namespaces in headers. BTW: Other than that, this issue has nothing to do with namespaces! There are two ways to resolve this:

1. Make the init function static, too. This separates all these constants and the function from their brethren in other translation units.
2. You only declare (`extern string const BYE;`) the constants in a header and implement them (`string const BYE = "Bye!";`) in a separate TU. That way you only have a single instance of them that can be shared by different parts of your program.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I thought that functions within a namespace were implicitly, already static as were the two strings `HI` and `BYE`. In such case, why are there multiple "copies" of the strings? I'm trying to avoid option 2, as I'm making a header only library; in fact, that's exactly the scenario that I'm trying to rewrite.

Answer (score -1):

I think this is due to the Initialization Fiasco. Following links may help you. The problem is that the Global/Static variables are initialized in a random manner. There is no particular order of initializing them. So maybe your HI_AND_BYE is initialized before HI or BYE is initialized.!!!

[Finding C++ static initialization order problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/335369/finding-c-static-initialization-order-problems)

http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/static-init-order.html

Comment: The initialization order of objects within a single translation unit is well-defined, it's in the order of their declaration. Note that e.g. the C++ FAQ at parashift's mentions objects "which exist in separate source files".