# How can I execute code once at runtime in multiple files without causing conflict?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, c++20

I have a module called Type that needs to be called upon by other classes to register their type. This only needs to happen once at the beginning of runtime. Here is an example of the cpp file:

```
// Initialize static variable (Types that are registered are added here)
std::unordered_map<String, Type::TypeNodeGen*> Type::_strMap;

// Called at the start of main
Type::Initialize() {
    Type::Register<int>("int");
    Type::Register<Transform>("transform"); // My own class
    Type::Register<Sprite>("sprite"); // My own class
    Type::Register<Physics>("physics"); // My own class
    // All other types that need to be registered
    // ...
}
```

There are a lot of Register calls and a lot of #includes in Type.cpp and I think the dependency should be reversed: Each file that needs its corresponding type added should call Register on their own.

I made a module called Once that allows you to execute a block of code as a static object is constructed:

```
using OnceFunc = std::function<void(void)>;

struct Once {
    // Constructor that calls the given function
    Once(OnceFunc func) { func(); }
};
```

Which works for Type.cpp:

```
std::unordered_map<String, Type::TypeNodeGen*> Type::_strMap;

// This works the same as before and isn't called from main
static Once init([&](void) {
    Type::Register<int>("int");
    Type::Register<Transform>("transform"); // My own class
    Type::Register<Sprite>("sprite"); // My own class
    Type::Register<Physics>("physics"); // My own class
});
```

But if I put a register call with Once in Transform.cpp for example, I get an exception in xhash in `_Find_last()` from the unordered_map _strMap that Type::Register() adds to:

`Exception thrown: read access violation. this->_Vec._Mypair._Myval2._Myfirst was 0x11101110111011A`

My guess is that I'm accessing an uninitialized unordered map since there is no guarantee of which order static objects will get initialized if they aren't in the same file.

Is there a better way to do this entirely or a way to make Once thread safe or something also without using a non standard library?

Comment: Use a static local variable in Get() to guarantee the initialization and use Get() in Register(). You don't need `Once`. You can make `static ... _strMap = Initialize();`.

Comment: *"or a way to make Once thread safe"* -- Since you're doing this during static initialization, it's not "thread safe" to be concerned with (you have not had a chance to make a second thread) but "[static initialization fiasco](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822181/prevent-static-initialization-order-fiasco-c)".

Comment: Right now, your question applies only to someone who has written the same registration system as you. It would be better to present the situation more abstractly. Show the the definition of your `unordered_map` in one file. Show two other files that add entries to the map during static initialization. Don't add much more -- just enough so that someone could copy and compile it (and possibly reproduce the result, but admittedly that depends on the toolchain). Focus on a more abstract presentation.

Comment: You need to find how to implement the Singleton design pattern properly. There has to be a lot of articles around.

Comment: @273K Very simple and effective, thank you; I tried using the getter and it worked. I am still wondering what the second part means though, How would that work for multiple files?