# __libc_init_array and global declared objects in cpp

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, libc

I have a micro controller c++ project where I declare as much as possible globally instead of newing objects. In fact, I am not using the `new` keyword anywhere.

I now ran into the situation where the order of the `__libc_init_array` is causing issues for me. I hope I can explain my situation well enough for somebody to point out if I am doing something horribly wrong, or if I can control the problem at hand.

I have a lot of classes, where dependencies are injected through the constructor. The objects are constructed when startup code calls into `__libc_init_array`. I now have one situation where the the constructor of class `B` is called before the constructor of class `A` is called, while `B` depends on `A`. So when the constructor of `B` uses any member of 'uninitialized' `A`, the app hard faults.

Is there a way to enforce the order of constructors called by `__libc_init_array`? Or did I make a horrible mistake relying on this behavior? Or... is it a bad idea to use members of dependencies in the constructor all together in c++?

I realize when I would `new` all objects I would have 100% control over this behavior construction order, but it's quite a bit of work to refactor that.

For now I added an `initialize` function for the single case where the dependency order is a problem, which solves the problem but doesn't feel like an appropriate solution either.

I tried to google for better solutions but keep coming up with non-related issues.

Comment: Sounds like [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).  Needs a [mre] to confirm.

Comment: The thing with globals is that things get link depenend (static initialization fiasco). You can get better control of life cycle by creating objects/arrays in main and injecting them into code that needs it. (Dependency injection) At least this should be a way out for your A/B situation. At least now you start to understand why using global variables is really not a good design pattern.

Comment: @NathanOliver thx for pointing out that link. It's exactly that. So the "best way" to prevent this is indeed accepting to `new` objects at least for startup? (the reason I was avoiding `new` all together is to stay away from dynamic memory allocations on an mcu, I guess for startup/initialization it doesn't have to be a problem)

Comment: @PepijnKramer, so that's exactly what you are proposing, right? `new` during startup to have control over this very problem

Comment: No I didn't say new, dynamic memory allocation is not needed

Comment: @bas You shouldn't need `new` to get this to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I meant something like this:

```
// from header file B.h

class A; // forward declaration

class B
{
public:
    // Inject dependency
    B(A& a) 
    {
    }
};

// from header file A.h
class A
{
};

// main.cpp
// include A.h and B.h

// if you had a function refering to global var b
// pass it in now.
void f(B& b)
{
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b{a}; // inject dependency on A

    // some function depending on B
    f(b);
}
```

Comment: Haha, let me re-iterate over this a little longer. But my first reaction is "why didn't I think of this....."

Comment: Probably because you were still really trying to understand and fix the problem you were facing. That sometimes makes it harder to take a step back ;)

Comment: Went for this, I like it. Fits my situation perfectly thx again

Comment: At least it give you full control over lifecycles ALL the time ;)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem recently, and discovered it is the [static initialization order fiasco](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof). If you have these classes in separate translation units, you [cannot prevent it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822181/prevent-static-initialization-order-fiasco-c).

I got around it, by declaring all my global classes which have dependencies in the main function and declaring them as `extern` in the respective header files.

```
// a.hpp
class A { /*...*/ };

extern A a;
```

```
// b.hpp
class B { /*...*/ };

extern B b;
```

```
// main.cpp

A a(/*...*/);  // guarantees that constructor of a is called before
B b(/*...*/);  // constructor of b
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place each global object in a function as a static variable, and have the function return a reference to it.

Instead of

```
// file x.cpp
X x;

// file y.cpp
Y y;
```

write:

```
// file x.cpp
X& get_x() { static X x; return x; }

// file y.cpp
Y& get_y() { static Y y; return y; }
```

Naturally you will have to replace references to `x` and `y` elsewhere with `get_x()` and `get_y()`.

This guarantees that the initialization order will conform to the dependency DAG (if it's indeed a DAG; if there is a dependency cycle, all bets are off). For example, if the constructor of `X` needs `y`, it can only get `y` via `get_y()`. This guarantees that `y` is constructed before the constructor of `X` can see it.

Comment: Can you explain what DAG stands for?

Comment: (minor detail: if the global objects are accessed frequently, this might incur performance penalty, because `get_x` and `get_y` need to check if the static variable has been initialized, every call, though the branch predictor and compiler are able to optimize it well.)

Comment: Ah, right. In my case the global variables are only accessed once, during startup, but still interesting remark

Comment: @bas directed acyclic graph

Comment: @0xbachmann right, this is something one needs to take into account.